# Ambiguous definition of the set of Natural Number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

According to the book "An introduction to the analysis of algorithms (written by Michael Soltys)", the author says in chapter 1 as follows.

> Let $\mathbb N = \{0, 1, 2,...\}$ be the set of natural numbers. Suppose that $S$ is a subset of $N $ with the following the two properties: first $0 \in S$, and second, whenever $n\in S$, then $n+1\in S$ as well. Then, invoking the Induction Principle(IP) we can conclude that $S=\mathbb N$.

I am wondering if it is fine to define the set of natural numbers like the author. Why the author put the number $0$ into the set of natural number $\mathbb N$?

Comment: If you’re asking whether it’s correct to include $0\in\Bbb N$, the answer is *yes*. It’s also correct to omit it: there are two different conventions. Most of us with a set-theoretic background automatically include it. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-0-a-natural-number) for more information; I think that it answers your question, so I’m voting to close yours as a duplicate.

Comment: " Regrettably, there seems to be no general agreement about whether to include 0 in the set of natural number":http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#History_of_natural_numbers_and_the_status_of_zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not $0$ is considered a "natural" number is a matter of convention.  I think including it is the better convention, since it is nice to have an additive identity even if inverses don't exist.  To avoid any doubt, use the terms "non-negative" integer and "positive" integer.

Comment: One convention I've seen is to call the set $\omega$ when 0 is meant to be included and $\mathbb{N}$ when it is not.