# Prove that there is a solution of $x^n = y^{n-1} +z^{n+1}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that for any $n\in N, n\neq0$, there exist $x,y,z\in N$, all non-zero, such that $x^n =y^{n-1}+z^{n+1}$.

Comment: There exists a non-zero solution for all $n>0$.  Hint: look for solutions where $y^{n-1} = z^{n+1}$.  What do $y$ and $z$ need to look like for that to happen?

Comment: @Avi: To many people $0\in\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: Is zero a natural number? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-0-a-natural-number

Comment: $2^2=1^3+3^1$ How does this sound?

Comment: Claudiu, I edited the question the best I could (with a bit of educated guessing). Please comment if it still looks strange :-)

Comment: And now you can start thinking in terms of Erick Wong's nice hint! I will purge the early comments as obsolete.

Comment: @AlexSilva Thanks for the reference. ( I grew up believing natural numbers start from 1, so it was interesting to see that post)

Comment: @Avi, you're welcome!