# If the range of function doesn't belong to its codomain, is this function valid?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, $f(x)=x-5\lfloor x/5\rfloor.$  Is this a valid function? At $x=20$ its value is $0$ which is not in its codomain?

Comment: Here [X] means box of X

Comment: Is this onto function

Comment: The definition is not valid, assuming that your $\mathbb{N}$ excludes zero.  Many authors do consider [zero to be a natural number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-0-a-natural-number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, no. A function is only well-defined if each element of the domain maps to (exactly) one element in the codomain.

However I assume that this particular $f$ came from a textbook or notes where the author allows natural numbers to include zero. There is unfortunately not universal consensus about whether $\mathbb{N}$ includes zero or not, and the charitable interpretation here is that $f$ is intended to map to and from $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.

Comment: This question was asked in jee  mains 2017 online paper of 9 april