# how many solutions to the equation $\vert x_1\vert+x_2+x_3 = 16$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many solutions to the equation $\vert x_1\vert +x_2+x_3 = 16 .$
we also know that $x_1 \in\mathbb Z$ and $x_2,x_3 \in\mathbb N$ .

in our class, $0 \in\mathbb N$ .

the answer in the textbook is : 17+ $2 \cdot{17\choose 2}$.

Thank you!!

Comment: [$0 \in \Bbb{N}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/283/290189)

Comment: It is twice the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=16$ with $x_1,x_2,x_3\in\mathbb N$, plus those of $x_2+x_3=16$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It is when we suppose $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$ right?

Comment: @ArsenBerk: absolutely.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Then I still don't get why I got that downvote for... If supposing $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$ gives a result as in your hint, then when we assume $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, my answer should be valid, isn't it?

Comment: @ArsenBerk: yep, $2\dfrac{16\cdot17}2+17$ solutions then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, we can find the number of solutions for $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 16$, say $A$, with $x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge 0$ and multiply them by $2$ (in order to count the solutions with negative values of $x_1$) and subtract the number of solutions for $x_1 = 0$, say $B$. (since we will be counting them twice). Long story short, we are seeking $2A-B$.

In order to find $A$ and $B$, we can make an analogy such that $A$ is the number of ways of putting $16$ balls to $3$ boxes without any restriction and $B$ is the number of ways of putting $16$ balls to $2$ boxes without any restriction. In order to find these numbers, we can use stars and bars or binary number representation. For example, if we put $1$ ball to $x_1$, $1$ ball to $x_2$ and $14$ balls to $x_3$, corresponding binary representation is $01010000000000000000$. So, total number of ways $A$ is the number of binary representations containing two $1$'s and sixteen $0$'s, which is $\binom{18}{2} = 153$. By similar logic, we can find $B$ as, $B = \binom{17}{1} = 17$. So the asnwer is $2A-B = 2 \cdot 153-17 = 289$.

Comment: Isn't it 225?  How does my answer get 225?

Comment: "Assuming $0 \in \mathbb{N}$". If $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$, $225$ is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is brute force, you can numerate the solutions:

- $x_1=0, (x_2,x_3)=(1,15),(2,14),(3,13),\cdots(15,1)\to 15$ solutions,
- $x_1=1, (x_2,x_3)=(1,14),(2,13),\cdots(14,1)\to 14$ solutions,
- $x_1=2, (x_2,x_3)=(1,13),\cdots(13,1)\to 13$ solutions,
- $\cdots$
- $x_1=14, (x_2,x_3)=(1,1)\to 1$ solution.

In total,

$$1+2+3+\cdots14+15+14+13+\cdots1=2\frac{14\cdot15}2+15=225.$$

---

Less brute force:

$x_2+x_3=n$ has $n-1$ solutions in $\mathbb N_{>0}$ (and $n+1$ in $\mathbb N_{\ge0}$).

Then $x_2+x_3=n-|x_1|$ has

$$\sum_{x_=-n+2}^{n-2}(n-1-|x_1|)=2\frac{(n-2)(n-1)}2+n-1=(n-1)^2$$

or, in $\mathbb N_{\ge0}$,

$$\sum_{x_=-n}^{n}(n+1-|x_1|)=2\frac{n(n+1)}2+n+1=(n+1)^2$$

solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we know that $x_1$ holds for any integer from $0$ to $14$, since $x_1$ is possible for all integers.  Now, $x_1$ cannot be $15$ or else, either $x_2$ or $x_3$ will be $0$, which is wrong.  So for $x_1=1$(do note that we cannot start from $x_1=0$ here, as negative $x_1$ is negative $0$, which is the same as $0$), $x_2+x_3=15$, and $x_2$ can range from $1$ to $14$, giving us $14$ ways.  When $x_1=1$, there are $14$ ways.  We observe a pattern here.  Finally, when $x_1=14$, there is only $1$ possibility.  We sum up $1$ to $14$, getting $\frac{15\times14}{2}=105$.  Negative values of $x_1$ hold here since $x_1$ is absoluted, so we multiply by $2$ to take care of there negative values.  We have $210$ ways here.  Not forgetting $x_1=0$, for that we have $15$ ways(since $x_2+x_3=16$, and $x_2$ and $x_3$ are greater than $0$).  Summing it up, we have $210+15=225$ ways.