# Methods for finding rules for ${s_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider $s_n=\{2,1,\frac{4}{5},\frac{5}{7},\frac{2}{3}, \ldots\}$

What are some techniques and tips that I can use to find the rules for such series? I find is extremely hard to do so and would like some help.

EDIT: I'm not necessarily,  looking for the rule of the specific example given, but some guidelines on to find rules on my own.

Comment: Such problems are usually ill-posed, but here we have 2/1,3/3,4/5,5/7,6/9, spot the pattern!

Comment: @Peter Wow I never would have thought about rewriting the rule like that!

Comment: Notice the proper way to code curly braces in MathJax, as in my edit to this question. $$ s_n = \{2,1,\ldots \} $$

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy :) I couldn't figure it out earlier lol

Comment: If you search for "pattern sequence" on this site you will find lots of discussions about why the very general question you are asking has not good answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=pattern+sequence

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems that it can be written into $$\left\{\frac{n+1}{2n-1}: n\geq1\right\}.$$

Comment: But what's the logic and thought process behind finding that rule? **How** did you find it?

Comment: It's kind of instinct rather than logic.

Comment: Dang, so it's not something I can learn how to do? :(

Comment: Also wait... $\frac{1+2}{2(1)-1}=3$...Am I that sleep deprived or is it not the correct rule. When n=1, it should be 2...

Comment: Sorry, it's been confusing for me whether natural number starts from $0$ or $1$...

Comment: Under what conditions am I allowed to start at 0? Sequences and series in my textbook almost always start at n=1. Therefore, starting at 0 wouldn't be valid for many problems.

Comment: Well, under the condition that you are in Europe perhaps... In fact, it doesn't really mater though, you may subtly adjust the formula.

Comment: @rainier whether you start at $0$ or you start at $1$ is usually **entirely** personal preference in strictly mathematical contexts.  In computer science contexts, many (*but not all*) programming languages have lists and arrays with entries starting with index $0$ which helps reinforce the habit in mathematical contexts as well.  If you ever worry that it is unclear whether you want to start from $0$ or $1$ then just explicitly state it.  See [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-0-a-natural-number).

Comment: @JMoravitz Noted! Thanks, this isn't the first time I got hung up over trivial things.