# Set theory notation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came across this notation

$$\bigcap _{i\in\mathbb{N} }(A_i \cup B_i)$$

while reading a paper on elementary set theory, but I'm not sure of what it means. (Perhaps the intersection of all sets $A_i \cup B_i$?)

Could anybody tell me?

Comment: It is $(A_1\cup B_1)\cap(A_2\cup B_2)\cap...\cap(A_N\cup B_N)\cap...$ So you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{N}$ is the set of indices, so you have an infinite intersection of sets that are indiced by natural numbers:

Informal:

$\bigcap_{i\in \mathbb{N}} (A_i\cup B_i)=(A_0\cup B_0)\cap (A_1\cup B_1)\cap (A_2\cup B_2)\cap\dotso$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-0-a-natural-number) makes me sad :(

Comment: @DonThousand Who cares about $0\in\mathbb{N}$ or $0\notin\mathbb{N}$. I like $0$ no matter if it is a natural number, or not!

Comment: I was just joking!

Comment: @DonThousand Me too!

Answer (score 0):

That's right, it's as you said.

$$\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N}(A_i\cup B_i)=\{x\mid \forall i\in\mathbb N,\,x\in A_i\cap B_i\}.$$