# Number of solutions of linear equation in $n$ unknowns with box constraints

Tags: integer-programming

Given the following linear equation in $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \in \mathbb positive\ integers\ including\ 0 $

$$C_1 x_1 + C_2 x_2 + C_3 x_3 + \dots + C_n x_n = 0$$

where $C_1, C_2, \dots, C_n \in \mathbb Z$    $$L \leq 
x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n \leq R$$

L and R are positive integers including 0

how can I find the **number of solutions**?

Comment: positive integers

Comment: I'm confused: *both* $C_i$ and $x_i$ are non negative? Sum of non negative numbers is non negative making it rather trivial.

Comment: Also, do we know if $L$ is positive or negative?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $\mathbb{N}$ is ambiguous. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-0-a-natural-number

Comment: What does $\mathbb Z_0^+$ mean? Thanks.

Comment: @NoChance Non-negative integers.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo - Oh, thanks.

Comment: @Radost sorry for the mistake $C_i$s belong to integer set both positive and negative

Answer (score 0):

Recursive approach leads to solution with $\mathcal{O}(n \max(|L|,|R|))$ by reducing this to problem of selecting sums from multiset $\{C_1,C_1,\dots,C_n\}$ with appropriate number of repetitions.

You are interested in this article for implementations:

[Wiki: Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)