# How do I show this set is not compact? $A = \left\{\frac{n+m}{nm}:n,m\in \mathbb{N} \right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

$A = \left\{\frac{n+m}{nm}:n,m\in \mathbb{N} \right\}$

How would I prove that A is **not** a compact set by using the definition  of a compact set?

I do not fully understand yet how a compact set works. I probably would have to find a subsequence with its limit outside of A but I would not know how to do that.

Comment: Prove that $(0,0)$  is a limit point of $A$ that does not belong to $A$,so $A$ is not closed..Compact subsets of the real line are exactly the closed and bounded sets.

Comment: Elements in $A$ are not defined if one of $m,n$ is $0$!

Comment: It is bounded, so show that it is not closed.

Comment: @Bernard: A common definition o the natural numbers is $1,2,3,..>$

Comment: Peano's axioms start at $0$. Natural numbers have one more element  than positive integers.

Comment: @Ned I think the limit there would be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Bernard https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-0-a-natural-number

Comment: Personally, I stick to Peano, and Bourbaki. Without $0$, it goes back to the times before $0$ was accepted as a number. $\mathbf N$ would not even be  a monoid!

Comment: I believe Peano started with $1$ (unitas). It is unfortunate that there is no widespread agreement.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that $\mathbb N=\mathbb Z_{>0}$.

Finding a sequence in $A$ whose limit is outside of $A$ is a good approach. This will show that $A$ is not closed, and therefore not compact.

Try looking at the sequence $\left(\frac{n+n}{n^2}\right)_{n\geq 1}$ in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Cover this set with the open sets $(1/k,\infty)$ for natural $k$. This is an open cover and so we must find some finite subcover if this will be a compact set. However if we take any finite collection of these open sets there exists a minimum $1/k_0$ among them. Since $\frac{n+m}{nm}$ can be made arbitrarily small by fixing $n$ or $m$ then increasing the other this finite collection cannot cover the set entirely. Since no finite subcover exists for this open cover the set cannot be compact.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the definition of compact but rather a property of compact sets, the [Bolzano Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

> **edit| this argument is wrong (thank you @PeterSzilas)**
>   Suppose for contradiction that $A$ were compact. Since the sequence
>   $(\frac{1+n}{n})_{n \geqslant 1}$ is contained in $A$, its limit, $1$,
>   would also be in $A$.
>
> But that would imply that there are $m,n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus
> > \{0\}$ such that $1=\frac{m+n}{mn}$, ie $m+n = mn$. But then  $$ m =
> > mn -n = n(m-1)$$  which implies  that $m=0$, a contradiction **(not, since $m=n=2$ is a solution)**.

**edit| consider this sequence instead :**
The sequance $\big(\frac{n+n}{n^2} \big)_{n \geqslant 0}$ is a sequence of elements of $A$, which converges to $0$, which isn't an element of $A$. By contraposition, $A$ is hence not compact.

Comment: Olivier: m=n=2?

Comment: @PeterSzilas Damnit I forgot to study the case where $n-1 = 1$! :-)

Comment: Olivier:m=mn-n=n(m-1);

Comment: @PeterSzilas Doh! Thank you for your vigilance, sir :)

Comment: Olivier: No worry :)