# Supremum of a very simple sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, sequence-of-function

Given $f_n(x)=nx$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, what is $\sup_n\{f_n(x)\}$.

I argue that the $\sup$ is $+\infty$.
My friend argue that it is

$$
\sup= \begin{cases} -\infty, & \mbox{if } x<0 \\ 0, & \mbox{if } x=0 \\ +\infty, &\mbox{if } x>0 \end{cases}
$$

We can't seem to understand this concept.

Comment: The $\sup$ cannot be $-\infty$, since the set is never empty.

Answer (score 1):

We have that, assuming $0\not \in \mathbb N$

- for $x>0 \implies f_n(x)=nx \to \infty$
- for $x=0 \implies f_n(x)=nx =0$
- for $x<0 \implies \max(f_n(x))=-x \implies \sup(f_n(x))=-x$

assuming $0 \in \mathbb N$ we would obtain

- for $x<0 \implies \max(f_n(x))=0 \implies \sup(f_n(x))=0$

Refer also to the related

- [Is $0$ a natural number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/283/505767)

Answer (score 0):

Let us define for $x \in \mathbb R$:

$$A_x:=\{nx: n \in \mathbb N\}.$$

1. If $x=0$, then $A_0=\{0 \}$, hence $ \sup A_0=0.$
2. If $x>0$, then $A_x$ is not bounded from above, hence $\sup A_x= \infty.$
3. If $x<0$, then $t <0$ for all $t \in A_x.$ Hence $0$ is an upper bound of $A_x.$ It is your turn to show that $\sup A_x=0$ , if $x<0.$