# Find all natural numbers $n$ where $n<1000$ such that cube of sum of the digits of $n$ be equal to $n^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Find all natural numbers $n$ where $n<1000$ such that cube of sum of
> the digits of $n$ be equal to $n^2$

For one digit numbers $n=1$ is the only answer. For two digits numbers $\overline{ab}$:

$$(10a+b)^2=(a+b)^3$$
$$100a^2+20ab+b^2=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$$

But it seems this method doesn't work because I can't simplify above equation.

Comment: Brute force seems pretty attractive.  Note that $S(n)$, the sum of the digits of $n$, satisfies $S(n)\equiv n\pmod 9$ so you need $n^3\equiv n^2\pmod 9$, which cuts the search down a lot.

Comment: $n^2$ is a perfect cube so $n$ is a perfect cube.

Comment: (Edited) Programming says the only solutions are $1$ and $27$ .

Comment: @NeatMath  Good point.  That makes it a paper and pencil computation.

Comment: @NeatMath Probably, you should post an answer :)

Comment: @VIVID no worries.  Between my first comment, and Neat Math's, we only need to check $1^3, 3^3, 6^3, 9^3$ and it is easy to eliminate the last two.

Comment: @lulu Yes, this has been a nice hack :D

Comment: @NeatMath  I second the motion for you to post your solution.  Personally, I tend to program things like this with little or no analysis (as the numbers are so small), but your comment makes this into something we can do mentally, which I find unexpected.

Comment: @lulu  and VIVID Thanks guys. Whoever summarizes our discussion and writes a solution does a favor to the community and deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use @lulu's notation for $S(n)$ to denote the sum of digits of $n$.  Using @NeatMath's observation that $(S(n))^3 = n^2$, we see that $n$ is a perfect cube, so it suffices to check the set $\{1^3,2^3,\dots,9^3\}$, due to the constraint $n < 1000 = 10^3$.  You might include $0$ if you have an affirmative answer to [Is $0$ a natural number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-0-a-natural-number).  $0$ and $1$ are trivial solutions.

@lulu's criterion $n^3 \equiv n^2 \pmod9$ restricts the searching to $1^3$, $3^3$, $6^3$ and $9^3$ because if $\gcd(n,9) = 1$, then the cancellation law gives $n\equiv1\pmod9$.

| $n$ | $S(n)$ | $(S(n))^3$ | $n^2$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $1^3 = 1$ | $1$ | $1$ | $1$ |
| $3^3 = 27$ | $2+7 = 9$ | $9^3 = 729$ | $729$ |
| $6^3 = 216$ | $2+1+6 = 9$ | $9^3 = 729$ | $46656$ |
| $9^3 = 729$ | $7+2+9 = 18$ | $18^3 = 5832$ | $531441$ |

Hence, there's only two solutions $1$ and $27$.

Comment: Wow, I like the table style! Where to learn more about this?

Comment: @VIVID That's GitHub-flavored Markdown table: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/259305.

Comment: We can eke out a little more.  The largest possible sum of 3 digits is $27$ and $27^3 = 19683$, so $n<\sqrt{19,683}<141.$  That eliminates $6$ and $9$ from the list.

Comment: @B.Goddard Great suggestion!  But I'd leave me answer as-is, as VIVID likes my table.  You may consider writing an answer for your additional criterion, so that we can give you credits for that.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Thanks for the link!

Comment: @VIVID You're welcome.