# What does the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N} \ | \ n \text{ is even}\}$ look like?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given the set builder notation $S = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \ | \ n \text{ is even}\}$, what does $S$ look like?

Does $S = \{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, ...\}$?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your are right. Only concerning is $0$ natural or not look https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-0-a-natural-number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no  consensus in Mathematics about if $0 \in \Bbb N$ or not. So, depending on the context or the area you are working, $0$ could be not included. Apart from that, you are right.