# Set Notation and usage

Tags: notation

I am working on a write-up and want to say that a variable is a positive integer (including zero). Would this be said as "variable is in the set of all nonnegative integers"? Maybe there is a different notation I should be using? In the event that I do want to use set notation, how would I write it in symbols?

Comment: I'd just say "the variable is a non-negative integer".  (Note: $0$ is *not* a positive number.  Positive means *strictly* greater than $0$)  There's no point is specifically saying "variable is in the set of all nonnegative integers" as *every* object is an element of the set that describes it.  It's enough to just say "variable is non-negative integer".  If you wont notation $x\in \{n\in \mathbb Z| n \ge 0\}$ is fine but there is also the notation $\mathbb Z^+$ which conventionally (and maybe confusedly) includes $0$.  There's also $\mathbb N \cup \{0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Saying that a variable is a nonnegative integer does include $0$. Sometimes people define the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ so that $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, though it is usually [explicitly stated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-0-a-natural-number).

In set builder notation, you could denote the set of nonnegative integers with $$\{x\in\mathbb{Z} \mid x \ge0\}$$

Answer (score 2):

You could say $x\in\mathbb{N}$ or $x\in\mathbb{Z^+}$. $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers and $\mathbb{Z^+}$ is the set of positive integers, which are essentially the same thing.

Comment: Another common notation is $\mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}$, which solves the ambiguity in both $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^+$ of whether you take them to mean “positive” or “strictly positive”.

Comment: The OP said he wants to include 0. He doesn’t just want *positive* integers.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine never saw that one before. The more you know.