# Given $T: (C[0,1], \|\cdot\|_1) \to (l^\infty,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ where $(Tf)_n = \int_0^1 x^nf(x)dx$, find $\|T\|$.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

> Given $T: (C[0,1], \|\cdot\|_1) \to (l^\infty,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ where $(Tf)_n = \int_0^1 x^nf(x)dx$, find $\|T\|$.

I've shown that $$\|Tf\|_\infty =\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left|\int_0^1 x^nf(x)dx\right| \le\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int_0^1x^n|f(x)|dx \le\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx =\|f\|_1.$$

If what I've done is correct then $\|T\| \leq 1$. Now I don't know how to continue to show that $\|T\| = 1$. Can I take $f = 1$ for this?

Comment: Does $0$ belong to [your](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283) $\Bbb N?$

Comment: It was not specified in the problem, but I guess it does belong to $\Bbb N$

Comment: Then yes $f=1$ proves your conjecture because $\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}|(Tf)_n|=(Tf)_0=1.$

Comment: What happens if it doesn't, I dont get it.

Comment: If $0\notin\Bbb N,$ you won't find an $f$ such that $\|f\|_1=1=\|Tf\|_\infty,$ but a sequence $(f_m)$ such that $\|f_m\|_1=1$ and $\|Tf_m\|_\infty\to1:$ take for instance $f_m(x)$ equal to $0$ on $[0,1-1/m],$ and to $2m^2(x-1+1/m)$ on $[1-1/m,1].$

Comment: Thanks for your help!