# Evaluating $0^0$ and its limit

Tags: limits, exponentiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zero to zero power](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-zero-power)

From what I understand $0^0$ is indeterminate, yet when you evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x^0$  you get 1 (given on wolframalpha.com).  Something seems wrong about this.

If wolframalpha is correct, how can this be?

Comment: See [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-zero-power). If $x\gt 0$, then $x^0=1$, so $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}x^0 = \lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}1 = 1$.

Comment: $x^0$ is not the only limit of this form. Indeterminate means that other limits might lead to other answers. For example, what is $\lim_{x \to 0} 0^x$?

Comment: Indeterminate, incidentally, does not mean undefined.  $0^0=1$ by definition, at least when the exponent is an integer $0$.  There are plenty of reasons for this, from convenience to counting arguments.  On the other hand $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined but not indeterminate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your limit is correct. The trouble is that is not the only way to approach $0^0$.

Consider $0^x$, $x>0$. Then the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ from above is equal to $0$. For the limit to exist, every pair of functions $f(x), g(x)$, with both functions approaching $0$ as $x \to 0$, must agree on $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)^{g(x)}$$

and these two examples show there are distinct pairs of functions which disagree on the limit.

(in this context, we might restrict to $f, g$ being nonnegative functions, but the same principle applies)