# What values of $0^0$ would be consistent with the Laws of Exponents?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am using the following fundamental properties of exponentiation on $N$ as as basis for this discussion:

(1) $0^1 = 0$

(2) $\forall x\in N (x\ne 0 \implies x^0 = 1)$

(3) $\forall x,y\in N (x^{y+1}=x^y\cdot x)$

Missing, of course, is a value for $0^0$. But only $0^0=0$ or $1$ are consistent with the Laws of Exponents:

(4) $\forall x,y,z\in N (x^{y+z}=x^y\cdot x^z)$

(5) $\forall x,y,z\in N (x^{y \space\cdot z}=(x^y)^z)$

**EDIT:**

From (5), we must have $(0^0)^2=0^{0\times 2}=0^0$. Therefore, $0^0= 0$ or $1$. Is this correct?

Is there any way to eliminate $0$ (or $1$) as a possible value, with reference to the fundamental properties or the laws of exponents?

Comment: I am sure this has been discussed before, but I note, from my own efforts, that it is not easy to find the previous questions which have raised the point.

Comment: Yes, this has been covered again and again, but there is a reason for that. We generally define $0^0=1$ on the natural numbers. This can be done in terms of set theory ($x^y$ being the size of $X^Y$ with $|X|=x,|Y|=y$.) It is also simpler - note how your (2) has a special case? Always unfortunate. The problem happens when you want $x^y$ to be continuous, but then you have a lot of problems - $x<0$, for example.

Comment: There was a discussion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/259514/32441)

Comment: I've been mystified by people trying to give a value to $0^0.$ It finally occurred to me that, in using summation signs for polynomials and power series, we use the shorthand $x^0$ to mean $1,$ and maybe people think that says something about $0^0.$ Hi, @OldJohn

Comment: There are indeed *many* postings on $0^0$ here -- maybe in every other math forum! -- but I am not asking for a value for $0^0$. There doesn't seem to be a consensus. But I have noticed that both $0^0=0$ and $0^0= 1$, at the very least, do seem to be consistent with the Laws of Exponents. I just wanted to confirm this fact.

Comment: Further, *only* $0$ or $1$ seem to work -- if you were to assign a value.

Comment: Indeed, it is similar to the case "$1/0 = \infty$" which is a non sense but people "take" it from
$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}{1 \over x} = \infty$. Similarly, 
$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}x^{x} = 1$ "yields" "$0^{0} = 1$".

Comment: $0^\text{negative}$ is undefined. So the idea that $0^0$ should be $0$ because $0^\text{positive}$ is always $0$ is pretty questionable. On the other hand, _any_ $\text{non-zero number}^0$ is unambiguously $1$. I have a take on this issue posted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238300/how-to-understand-why-x0-1-where-x-is-any-real-number/238338#238338).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1

Answer (score 7):

If $c,d$ are cardinal numbers, then $c^d$ is the cardinal of the set of maps $d \to c$. This works for *all* cardinal numbers and the usual arithmetic laws hold. For $d=0$ we get $c^0=1$ since there is a unique map $\emptyset \to c$. This holds for *all* $c$, in particular $0^0=1$. So there is actually no debate what $0^0$ is or not, it is $0^0=1$ by the general definitions. No case distinctions are necessary. Forget about $0^0=0$, this is nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this may be glib, but following up on the comment of Will Jagy above, consider the following:

$$
  1 = 1^n = (1+0)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} 1^i \cdot 0^{n-i}.
$$

Do you see what I'm getting at?  What sense do we want to make out of the last term, $1^n \cdot 0^0$?

---

Actually, I need to clarify why I posted this as an "answer."  Since the OP is looking to define $0^0$ in a way that stays consistent with "fundamental properties of exponents," and I feel that the Binomial Theorem is fundamental enough to qualify as essential to arithmetic, the example above rules out the possibility of $0^0 = 0$ while reinforcing $0^0=1$.

Comment: I think the proof of BT assumes $0^0=1$.

Comment: Also, BT, as usually stated, assumes $0^0=1$. But it could easily be re-stated without this assumption, handling the zero-cases as exceptions similar to other exceptions for zero-denominators. Yes, it would be awkward.

Comment: Of course, the PROOF of BT needs the assumption $0^0 = 1$, but here it is raised to an AXIOM which then actually implies the assumption; this means that $0^0=1$ is equivalent to BT.

Answer (score 1):

Dan, the proof of BT indeed assumes 0^0=1.  The problem is that:

(a) there are many places where we assume 0^0 = 1,  and
(b) people do not acknowledge (a).

Calculus textbooks usually say that 0^0 is undefined, but at the same time, they contain dozens of formulas that assume 0^0=1.

Textbooks should honestly admits that it is standard practice to evaluate 0^0 to 1.

The argument for "undefined" is based on the mistaken belief that 0^0=1 leads to contradictions. It does not (if it did, we would have found out long ago, because the assumption 0^0=1 is used in subtle ways in lots of places).

But the real reason that I feel strongly that 0^0 must be 1 is because the "undefined" idea is contrary to a two deeply held convictions, namely (1) that the most convenient definition must be the best one, and (2) math is consistent, so given the fact that set theory tells us 0^0=1, it means that it is OK to use that everywhere.

Comment: The problem in calculus is that choosing value for $0^0$ is choosing whether or not $0^x$ is continuous or $x^0$ is continuous, or seeing that $x^y$ cannot be continuous as a function of two variables.

Comment: Stewart (admittedly the only calculus book in easy reach) writes that $0^{0}$ is _indeterminate_ (which is perfectly true), not "undefined". Can you supply specific citations of calculus authors who use "undefined" in this context, and/or do you dispute that $0^{0}$ is indeterminate?

Comment: I checked 4 calculus books, and they write that x^0 = 1 if x is not 0. They should write: x^0=1 for every x because that is what they actually use in several formulas.

Comment: Asaf, even from the viewpoint of the function 0^x, the value 1 is better than the value 0. This function provides two values (0 and infinity)
depending on whether x approaches 0 from the right or the left. Picking one of these two values is a arbitrary choice, and by symmetry a^(-x) =    
1/a^x you can see that both choices must be wrong. The only value that is supported by a consistent argument is the value 1.

Comment: If $0^0 =1$ then $0 = 0^{-2} \cdot 0^2 = 0^0=1$.

Answer (score 0):

We can make sense of $0^0=1$ in this way also : Expand $f(x)=a^x$ as Taylor series for real values of x and a is fixed positive real number and let a tends to zero. Its not rigorous but still supporting our assumption.

Answer (score -1):

**Follow-up**

It can be shown that there exists not just 1 or 2 "exponent-like" functions on *N* as I suggested here, but an *infinite* number of them. And from any one of them, we can derive the usual Laws of Exponents. For formal proofs, see [Oh, the ambiguity!](http://dcproof.wordpress.com/) at my blog.