# Is there any good reason not to define $0^0=1$ , such as contradictions in algebra or arithmetic?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Math people:

The title is the question: Is there any good reason not to define $0^0=1$ , such as contradictions in algebra or arithmetic?

I searched for similar questions before I posted this question, and couldn't find any.  After I posted it,  I got some comments citing similar questions.  There is a similar question at [What values of $0^0$ would be consistent with the Laws of Exponents?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485102/what-values-of-00-would-be-consistent-with-the-laws-of-exponents) .  I checked some of the other questions in the links in the comments and the links posted with those links.  There is a closer match at [How to define the $0^0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259514/how-to-define-the-00) That question was closed as a duplicate, but the older, duplicated question was not identified.  I could not find a convincing answer anywhere to my essential question: "does defining $0^0=1$ lead to contradictions in algebra and arithmetic?" I'll leave it up to others to decide whether my question is a duplicate.  If it is, maybe you can close this question and give a better (in my opinion) answer to one of the older questions.

Let me get one thing out of the way up front: yes, I know "$0^0$" is an indeterminate form.  That is, if $f$ and $g$ are real-valued functions with $f(t) \to 0^+$ as $t \to 0$ and $g(t)\to 0$ as $t \to 0$, then you don't know what $\lim_{t\to 0}f(t)^{g(t)}$ is, or even whether exists, without more information.  I don't consider this a good reason to declare that $0^0$ itself must be considered undefined.  I know many people will disagree with me here.  I expect at least one answer and some comments arguing why this is a good reason for $0^0$ to be considered undefined.  Everyone is entitled to their opinion, and you are free to leave such an answer.  I will not attempt to change your mind, beyond what I write in this question.

If you define $f(x,y) = x^y$, then $f$ cannot be continuous on $[0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$ no matter what value, including $1$, you assign to $f(0,0)$.  But why should every function have to be continuous?

If the mathematical community ever does come to the consensus that $0^0=1$, and I were teaching calculus students about limits involving indeterminate forms, I probably would not even mention the question of whether $0^0$ itself had a value, because it probably just confuse the students.  They probably wouldn't even notice the omission.

To me, a "good reason" not to define $0^0=1$ would be if this definition resulted in a contradiction, when used in expressions involving multiplication and exponentiation of real numbers and the rules used to simplify such expressions.  Here is an attempt to produce such a contradiction: assuming $0^0=1$, $(0^0)^2=1^2=1$, and $(0^0)^2=0^{(0*2)}=0^0=1$.  No contradiction.  In constrast, if you define $0/0 = 1$ and you want the associative property to hold (a reasonable expectation), then you can derive the contradiction $1=0/0=(2*0)/0=2*(0/0)=2*1=2$.

It just occurred to me that there is another good reason for not declaring officially that $0^0$ must always equal $1$: if defining $0^0=0$ does not lead to contradictions in algebra or arithmetic, either.

I am *not* claiming $0^0 = 0/0$.  Of course you can never divide by zero, or raise zero to a negative power.

Of course, when people use power series, they use $0^0=1$ all the time, and no one complains.  I have read that "$0^0=1$" is used often in combinatorics, but I don't know much about combinatorics.

Based on what I have seen in the older questions, their answers, and the answers and comments to this question, it seems that no one has discovered any way in which defining $0^0$ to be $1$ leads to contradictions when using the usual rules of multiplication and exponentiation.  It also seems that defining $0^0$ to be $0$ does not lead to such a contradiction. So I'm guessing it is impossible to produce such a contradiction.  But I have never heard of anyone wanting to define $0^0$ as $0$.

Comment: There has been more than several questions on the topic recently.

Comment: Rather than saying "does it lead to contradictions" I would say "does it violate any of the basic identities of arithmetic?"

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495121/both-00-and-01-are-undefined http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485102/what-values-of-00-would-be-consistent-with-the-laws-of-exponents and you can probably follow the related and linked threads from the right hand side of the screen as well.

Comment: A sensible convention: $0^0=1$ when the exponent is the integer zero, but $0^0$ is undefined when the exponent is the real number (or complex number) zero.  Then you can work on conventions for $p$-adic numbers and finite fields, too...

Comment: @Gedgar : I upvoted your comment.  If you reject continuity/limit reasons, as I do, then it seems to me that it shouldn't matter whether you consider the exponent a real number or an integer (maybe it should, I just can't think of a good reason).  I have not even thought about complex exponents.  Exponentiation involving complex numbers is fraught with problems that I want to avoid.

Comment: Whether you like it or not, being discontinuous *is* a good reason to leave it undefined at $0^0$. In settings where continuity is important and discontinuous functions need special care, using the discontinuous version of exponentiation rather than a continuous version does nothing but get in the way and make things more complicated for no reason. Save your urges to define $0^0$ for those settings where it's *actually appropriate*, such as when expressing repeated products, or doing polynomial arithmetic.

Comment: Note that defining $0/0=1$ leads to no contradictions in algebra or arithmetic, if you handle it with the same care that you have to use when handling $0^0=1$ in the continuous context.

Comment: @Hurkyl : I upvoted your "Whether you like it or not comment" because you mention "the discontinuous version of exponentiation", in which $0^0$ does not equal $1$, if I understand properly.

Comment: @Stefan: If you're going to make the analyst take care to avoid "$\lim x^y = (\lim x)^{\lim y}$", then the algebraist should take care not to use $(xy)/y = x$.

Comment: @Stefan: Ah, my mistake: it's $(ab)/c = a(b/c)$ I should have asked you to be careful to avoid!  I don't take it personally: I really do understand why people would want to insist on $0^0=1$ being defined: it is very useful in many settings, and the really strong reasons to avoid it (in the settings where you should do so) are rather subtle, and depend on things that aren't usually made clear. It's really easy to just say "Oh, just be careful to avoid the times where this causes problems" without realizing the monkey wrench that puts into your thinking in certain settings.

Comment: @moderators: can we make "0^0" a key word in searching in a way that more effectively yields the multitude of questions regarding this topic? There are many questions like this, but it is true that it is hard to find them by searching, I suppose because 0^0 is wrapped up in the LaTeX?

Comment: The continuity requirement is not such a strange one when you consider that the real numbers are defined to be limit-like objects. So asserting $0^0=1$ over the reals does seem questionable - it will depend upon how you define exponentiation. Rudin has $a^x$ being a supremum of all $a^q$ with $q$ rational and $q<x$. With $a=0$ allowed, this would suggest $0^0=0$. (He requires a>0.) So, it's not a small offense to violate the continuity of $x^y$. But, in many contexts, it is reasonable to advocate $0^0 = 1$, because it can be interpreted reasonably and is very convenient.

Comment: @alex.jordan : I think I searched for "0^0=1" and I got some hits for questions involving zero _divided_ by zero, but nothing about $0^0$. I don't know if searching for $\TeX$ expressions in question titles works at all, or is supposed to work.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the very least, the answer $0^0 = 1$ is consistent with cardinal arithmetic on the set $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$. Under this interpretation, the number $m^n$ is defined to be the number of functions from an $n$-element set to an $m$-element set. There is exactly one function from a $0$-element set to a $0$-element set, so in this interpretation, $0^0 = 1$. The laws $a^m a^n = a^{m+n}$ and $(a^m)^n = a^{mn}$ can be proven with that definition. Thus, exponentiation as repeated multiplication can be recovered. (In one of your links, Matt N. gives this same idea as an answer.)

The first criticism I heard involved the subtraction law $\frac{a^x}{a^y} = a^{x-y}$. The idea is that $\frac{0^x}{0^x} = 0^0$, yet $\frac{0^x}{0^x} = \frac{0}{0}$, so $0^0$ is undefined. The problem here isn't with $0^0$, it's with saying $\frac{0^x}{0^x}$ is equal to anything, when it is undefined. We could use the same reasoning to say that $0^2$ is undefined, since $0^2 = \frac{0^7}{0^5} = \frac{0}{0}$. At worst, the subtraction law has to be modified to say that it only applies when $a^y \neq 0$. We make such modifications for all of our other laws involving division, so why should this be any different?

Comment: Using $0^2/0^2$ do disallow $0^0$ is foolish: one can't divide by $0$ in any case, so what would this mean? By the same reason also $1/1$ would be disallowed, because $\frac{1\cdot0}{1\cdot0}$ has no meaning.

Comment: @StefanSmith I know and I agree with Hugh; I just wanted to add a different point of view on the same argument: division by $0$ is not allowed, so $0^0=0^2/0^2$ is *not* a valid argument.

Comment: @egreg : It occurred to me after I left my comment that maybe you were actually agreeing with Hugh.  Of course, I wrote in my question that I was not claiming $0^0=0/0$, to prevent anyone from making this argument.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Hugh : I have a feeling my question will be closed soon, so I went ahead and accepted your answer, which is good.  I will add a little something to the end of my question, if you have a moment to look at it.

Comment: Thanks - I'd actually be surprised if even in this deeper "where does $0^0 = 1$ break down?" type question if it wasn't some sort of duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

In many settings, the point-set version of the notion of function is a useful fiction, but is ultimately wrong.

For example, in real analysis, the value of a function at a point is pretty much *wholly irrelevant* -- it is only the "bulk" behavior of a function in a regino that matters. The value of an integrand at individual points already has no bearing whatsoever to a Riemann integral. Most operations are implicitly modified to append "... and then take the continuous extension of the result" to their usual meaning. The definition of "derivative" eventually gets refined to the point where discontinuities get washed out. One even works with objects like the dirac delta function that *can't even be fully described* by specifying its 'values' at all points.

> **Definition**: The **cvalue** of a function $f$ at the point $a$ is defined to be, if the it exists and is unique, the value $g(a)$ where $g$ is a function continuous at $a$ and differs from $f$ at only finitely many points. This value will be notated $f[a]$.

(replace "finitely many points" with "a set of measure zero" to get a better definition, if you know what that means)

The name and notation is made up for this post -- I think analysis would simply call this the "value" of $f$ at $a$ and assume that their colleagues know what they mean.

When limits exist, we can compute them simply by plugging in cvalues:

$$ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f[a] $$

It's also not too hard to see, for example, that

$$ \int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \int_a^b f[x] \, dx $$

so we can already see that cvalues are already good enough for computing integrals.

Also, recall that the major property of the dirac delta function is that if $f$ is *continuous* at zero, we have

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \delta(x) \, dx = f(0) $$

This generalizes to

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \delta(x) \, dx = f[0]$$

when $f$ is discontinuous at zero.

Another nice example is that the partial function $f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$ and the function $g(x) = 1$ satisfy $f[x] = g[x]$ everywhere.

I hope these give some of the flavor of why cvalues have importance.

The point of bringing all of this up is that in the continuous context, putting emphasis on values at individual points is the wrong way to think about things. Setting $0^0 = 1$ washes out, because the *cvalue* of $x^y$ doesn't exist at $0^0$. However, continuous functions are very special because they are *much* easier to manipulate and work with and have loads of nice properties. Modifying exponentiation to be discontinuous makes it awkward to take advantage of the nice features that exponentiation would otherwise have from its status as being continuous on the region defined by $x > 0$ and on $x = 0 \wedge y > 0$.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because of the time and thought you evidently put into it, but as the question says, I am mainly interested in whether defining $0^0$ to be $1$ leads to contradications in algebra and arithmetic, when you use basic laws of multiplication and exponentiation, not in questions of analysis, derivatives, continuity, limits, integrals, etc.

Comment: @Stefan: Ah, I misunderstood: I thought you were looking for a good explanation of why $0^0 = 1$ should be avoided (when appropriate). It really is fine in algebraic contexts, as you've observed, except possibly if you start doing some esoteric things (none of which spring to mind at the moment)

Comment: If nothing else, it was a worthwhile exercise for me, since I'm better prepared for the next time I talking about just why it matters in the continuous version. Maybe I'll find one of the older $0^0$ posts and copy it there.

Comment: I read this answer, and come to the opposite conclusion. As you say, the value of $0^0$ has no relevance in analysis: functions like $0^x$ (or functions where you care about continuity in the exponent) are **already** discontinuous at $0$, and this won't change whether or not you accept that $0^0=1$. So there seems no reason not to. (On the other hand, $x^0$, which can be given a meaning even for negative $x$, is continuous with $0^0=1$.) So the only reason not to define $0^0$ is vague fears like "possibly if you start doing some esoteric things (none of which spring to mind at the moment)".

Comment: @ShreevarsR : although I upvoted Hurkyl's answer, I also upvoted your comment, which is a good argument for defining $0^0=1$, or rather a good argument against many arguments against defining $0^0=1$ (sorry for the convoluted wording).  It is impossible to make the function $x^y$ continuous at $(0,0)$, so it seems silly to object to defining $0^0$ to be $1$ because it makes $x^y$ discontinuous at $(0,0)$.  On the other hand, Hugh Denoncourt makes a good point in his comment below my question.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR : the best reason I can think of not to define $0^0$ as $1$ is that you can also define it to be $0$.  I read an earlier post that showed these are the only possible values that can be assigned to $0^0$ without violating rules of algebra, and I'm pretty sure that $1$ and $0$ don't violate those rules.  I've never heard of anyone wanting to use $0$ as the value of $0^0$.

Comment: @StefanSmith: Well, defining it to be $0$ breaks a lot of things (such as the combinatorial interpretation), while defining it to be $1$ is well-motivated and breaks essentially nothing (e.g. the lack of satisfying answers to this question ☺). (Another point: there is no way of extending the function $0^n$ to $n < 0$, so it's a function that already has a "break". But there *is* a way of defining $n^0$ for all $n$, which is broken only if you declare that $0^0$ is not $1$.)

Comment: This has very little to do with the question, but it was a lovely read nonetheless. +1

Comment: Hurkyl, is there any difference between $f[x]$ and $\mathrm{lim}_{X \rightarrow x} f(X)$?

Comment: @goblin  It does have something to do with the question. We need exact numbers to evaluate $0^0$.  Hurkyl essentially denies the usefulness or existence of exact numbers (without realizing that this makes it impossible to write proofs, define real numbers, etc.).

Comment: @goblin a very late comment: they differ in the case where $f[x]$ is defined using the "set of measure $0$" definition, but not if it is defined using the "finitely many points" definition.

Answer (score -1):

The fact that 0^0 = 1 follows directly from a widely accepted theorem (the
binomial theorem). Thus, the claim that 0^0 is undefined is equivalent to the claim that widely accepted mathematical results are mutually inconsistent.

This is a huge claim considering the fact that nobody has found any inconsistencies in over a hundred years!

The reality is that (a) 0^0 is 1 in every formula that contains x^n,
(examples: binomial theorem, Taylor series, polynomials, Vandermonde matrix, power rule, etc.), and (b) nobody has ever found any contradiction arising from this.

In all other parts of mathematics if A ==> B, and A is a widely accepted theorem, then we must accept B as well. Nevertheless, some people reject this when B is a statement that conflicts with their gut intuition such as 0^0 = 1. They would rather rely on ad-hoc arguments like limits instead of accepting corollaries of well established theorems.  The only explanation I can come up with for this phenonemon is that even in the modern age, people are still uncomfortable with accepting 0 as a number, or {} as a set.

Comment: Um.  How about the inconsistency mentioned in the first answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259514/how-to-define-the-00

Comment: Before I answer that, let me make sure: Are you claiming that widely accepted math is mutually inconsistent?  My claim is that it is not.

Comment: @anorton: That is not an inconsistency: the fact that $0^x = 0$ for all *positive* $x$ (only) does not force anything about the value $x=0$, especially considering the fact that $0^x$ cannot be defined for any $x<0$.

Comment: The 0^x argument does not support 0 as a value because the left limit is infinity or undefined, depending on the way you want to treat it, while the right-limit is 0, but by a symmetry argument you can see that both are bad choices.
But the bigger question is: do you think that generally accepted math is mutually contradictory?

Comment: Ehh... ok.  I think I agree with your statement of "it is consistent," but I disagree that the binomial theorem implies this to be the case.  (In most handling of series/summation that I have seen, $0^0$ is *defined* to be $1$ for notational convenience.)  Whatever--I'll have to think more about this issue... :)

Comment: @Mark Furthermore: if you ever encounter a $0^0$ case in the binomial theorem, you no longer have a binomial. `:)`  (E.g. $(x-0)^5 = x^5$.  You don't need the binomial theorem.  That is, the interpretation $0^0 = 1$ is *consistent* with the binomial theorem, but the binomial theorem does not *imply* that)

Comment: The binomial theorem also implies (1-1)^0 = 1^0 * (-1)^0.

For power series, one can ask if it is consistent to say that if 0^0 appears in a power series, then it is 1, but if it appears by itself, then it is not? I don't see how to make that happen in a consistent way.

If 0^0 really was undefined, then the only consistent option I see is to introduce a new function, say pow(x,n), which is defined as x^n if (x,n)<>(0,0) and 1 if (x,n) = (0,0).  Next, we have to replace every formula that contains an x^n by pow(x,n). What you'll find is that the "old" x^n would no longer be used anywhere.