# $0^0$ -- indeterminate, or $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

One of my teachers argued today that 0^0 = 1. However, WolframAlpha, intuition(?) and various other sources say otherwise... 0^0 doesn't really "mean" anything..

can anyone clear this up with some rigorous explanation?

Comment: The problem is that it's ambiguous: there are several things one might *actually mean* by writing $0^0$, and they don't agree. The most common meanings of the notation $0^0$ would make it undefined, indeterminate, or $1$.

Comment: I like $0^0=1$. Makes sense for algebraic manipulations.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1

Comment: 0^0 = (0^2)/(0^2) = 0/0 = undefined, no?

Comment: As [this](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node14.html) explains, it really depends on the context.

Comment: @Hurkyl what is the difference between "undefined" and "indeterminate" ?

Comment: I'm kind of curious; can someone explain why this question was downvoted?

Comment: @recursive recursion it's a duplicate

Comment: "Undefined" is like gibberish: the symbols simply aren't allowed to be put together that way. "Indeterminate" is an adjective applied to *limit forms*. e.g. as $x \to 0$, the expression $x/x$ has the *indeterminate form* $0/0$, which means we can't determine the value of the limit of $x/x$ as $x \to 0$ simply by plugging in the limit of all the parts of the expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short answer:** It depends on your convention and how you define exponents.

**Long answer:** There are a number of ways of defining exponents. Usually these definitions coincide, but this is not so for $0^0$: some definitions yield $0^0=1$ and some don't apply when both numbers are zero (leaving $0^0$ undefined).

For example, given nonnegative whole numbers $m$ and $n$, we can define $m^n$ to be the number of functions $A \to B$, where $A$ is a set of size $n$ and $B$ is a set of size $m$. This definition gives $0^0=1$ because the only set of size $0$ is the [empty set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set) $\varnothing$, and the only function $\varnothing \to \varnothing$ is the [empty function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_function).

However, an analyst might not want $0^0$ to be defined. Why? Becuase look at the limits of the following functions:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} 0^x = 0, \qquad \lim_{x \to 0} x^0 = 1, \qquad \lim_{x \to 0^+} (e^{-1/t^2})^{-t} = \infty$$
All three limits look like $0^0$. So when this is desired, you might want to leave $0^0$ undefined, so that it's a lack of definition rather than a discontinuity.

Typically this is resolved by:

- If you're in a *discrete* setting, e.g. considering sets, graphs, integers, and so on, then you should take $0^0=1$.
- If you're in a *continuous* setting, e.g. considering functions on the real line or complex plane, then you should take $0^0$ to be undefined.

Sometimes these situations overlap. For example, usually when you define functions by infinite series
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$$
problems occur when you want to know the value of $f(0)$. It is normal in these cases to take $0^0=1$, so that $f(0)=a_0$; the reason being that we're considering what happens as $x \to 0$, and this corresponds with $\lim_{x \to 0} x^0 = 1$.

Comment: thanks a lot, this clears up a lot of the confusion and gives me insight to the nature of indeterminate forms.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following sequences:

$0,0^\frac{1}{2},0^\frac{1}{3},0^\frac{1}{4},\cdots$

$(\frac{1}{2})^0,(\frac{1}{3})^0,(\frac{1}{4})^0,\cdots$

The first evaluates to a sequence of 0s that would imply a limit of $0^0\implies0$ as each term is zero.

The second evaluates to a sequence of 1s that would imply a limit of $0^0\implies1$ as each term is one.

However, as each value is different this would imply that there isn't a value for $0^0$ as generally one would think $0^a=0$ for any positive a, while $x^0=1$ for any non-zero x as a couple of identities that conflict here.

Comment: so it's.. both?

Comment: No, by having different values, I'm saying it isn't computable.

Comment: ambiguous, so you can't define it?

Comment: Interesting. I need this for a proof that $\exp(0) = 1$. I was writing out the definition in terms of the infinite series, but the first term is obviously $0^0$ . . .

Comment: @JBKing I want to expand on this idea past just $0^0$ - We can take it to be 1, but I haven't seen such possibilities for other indeterminate forms: $\frac{\infty}{\infty} , \frac{0}{0},$ etc are there any other indeterminate forms in which we can reasonably assign a value when we need to?

Comment: Ever look into L'Hopital's Rule? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule may be useful for other indeterminate forms. $f(x)=\frac{k*sin(x)}{x}$ for any constant k evaluated in the limit as x tends to 0 will tend to the constant k.

Comment: @terribleatmath, no problem. Just take $\mathrm{e}^0 = \lim_{x \to 0} \mathrm{e}^x$, then the $x^0 = 0$ all the way.

Answer (score 0):

> *One of my teachers argued today that $0^0 = 1$.*

He probably meant that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to0}n^n=1$, which is indeed true.

> *$0^0$ doesn't really "mean" anything...*

Of course it does... It's just that its meaning depends on the given *context*, yielding *different* results for *different* cases, as has already been explained above... As opposed to, say, $1+1$, which is *always* $2$, being *independent* on context.

Comment: The teacher probably meant that $0^0=1$, which doesn't contradict anything, without mentioning limits, which are a different topic.