# What is the zeroth power of the Null Matrix $\left(\begin{array}{ll}{0} & {0} \\ {0} & {0}\end{array}\right)^{0}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I was trying to play around with matrix esponentials and proving a fundamental theorem of trigonometry analogon for this type structure. As it might happen, I ran across the problem in the title, while computing e^(zero matrix).
I highly suppose it's the unit matrix, but is there a proper way to prove it?

Comment: It's undefined, as $0^0$ is undefined.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/699740/471884

Comment: It's obviously the identity matrix, by definition. Powers with nonnegative exponent are defined by recursion: $A^0=I$, $A^{n+1}=A^nA$. No proof is needed for a definition.