# Find $\lim_{x→0^-} f(x)$ if $f(x) =x^x$,

Tags: calculus

$x^x = (e^{\log x})^x = e^{x \log x}$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} e^{x \log x} = e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} x \log x}$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} x \log x
 = \lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} \frac{\log x}{(\frac{1}{x})}
 = \lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} \frac{(\log x)'}{(\frac{1}{x})'}
 = \lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{(-\frac{1}{x^2})}
 = \lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} -x = 0$

Im stuck

Comment: Perfect! So $\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} x^x = e^0 = 1$.  The limit from the left is not defined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zero to the zero power - Is $0^0=1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1)

Comment: you have everything in the right place.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!

Comment: When you say "$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} e^{x \log x} = e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} x \log x}$", is $\log x$ well defined for negative $x$?

Comment: @Alizter Not quite; that one is about defining $0^0$, not about the limit. I could not find a duplicate for this particular (odd) question.

Comment: What is $(-1/2)^{-1/2}$?

Answer (score 0):

You will have no luck in finding the limit as $x$ approaches zero from below, because the complex function 
$$
f(z) = z^z
$$
Has a branch cut along the negative real axis ending at the origin.

Thus for example, taking $z \rightarrow 0$ along the imaginary axis, we find that 
$(iy)^{iy}$ goes to $-\infty$ as $y \rightarrow 0^+$.  Whenever there is an endpoint of a branch cut of a function, there will be some direction along which the limit is undefined, and the negative real axis is that path for this function.

Comment: While this is a very informative, it is *way* above the level of the poster and is entirely unhelpful to OP.