# "Proving" that $0^0 = 1$

Tags: limits, fake-proofs, indeterminate-forms

I know that $0^0$ is one of the seven common indeterminate forms of limits, and I found on wikipedia two very simple examples in which one limit equates to 1, and the other to 0. I also saw here: [Prove that $0^0 = 1$ using binomial theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032293/prove-that-00-1-using-binomial-theorem) 
that you can define $0^0$ as 1 if you'd like.

Even so, I was curious, so I did some work and seemingly demonstrated that $0^0$ always equals 1.

**My Work:**

$$y=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}{(x^x)}$$

$$\ln{y} = \lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}{(x\ln{x})} $$

$$\ln{y}= \lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}{\frac{\ln{x}}{x^{-1}}} = -\frac{∞}{∞} $$

$\implies$ Use L'Hôpital's Rule

$$\ln{y}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{x^{-1}}{-x^{-2}} $$
$$\ln{y}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} -x = 0$$
$$y = e^{0} = 1$$

What is wrong with this work? Does it have something to do with using $x^x$ rather than $f(x)^{g(x)}$? Or does it have something to do with using operations inside limits? If not, why is $0^0$ considered indeterminate at all?

Comment: Yes, using $x^x$ rather than $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is exactly what you're doing wrong. Imagine doing it with $f(x) = x, g(x) =0$ or the other way around, and see what you get.

Comment: Indeed. Consider $\lim_{x\to0+}x^0$ and $\lim_{x\to0+}0^x$. You're really concerned with the question of whether $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0+,0+)}x^y$$ exists.

Comment: When you move the logarithm inside the limit you have already assumed that the limit of $x^x$ exists.

Comment: I deleted my post because apparently people disagreed, but I have often seen $0^0$ to be defined as $1$, particularly in combinatorics. This is a matter of convention though, and the limit will always be undefined for the reason above by MPW.

Comment: @KayleoftheCreeks but it's still true that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x=1$, it just doesn't have anything to do with why $0^0$ is often left undefined.

Comment: @Elliot: Yes, *in combinatorics* $0^0$ is defined to be $1$. In *analysis*, not so much.

Comment: @Rahul In analysis quite often! Consider power series... (see the answer I posted).

Comment: I think that taking limits in proving $0^0 = 1$ isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Rahul Compare: Just because $\lim_{x\to 0}\operatorname{sgn} x$ does not convereg doesn't mean that $\operatorname{sgn}(0)$ is undefined. And even in analytics, people will agree that the derivative of $x\mapsto x^a$ is $x\mapsto ax^{a-1}$ also for the specific case $a=1$, which seems to imply that "they" do assume $0^0=1$.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: There is no need to prove that $0^0=1$ because it follows directly from the definition $x^n=x \cdots x$ ($n$ $x$'s) and the empty product rule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone said that $0^0=1$ is correct, and got a flood of downvotes and a comment saying it was simply wrong. I think that someone, me for example, should point out that while saying $0^0=1$ is correct is an exaggeration, calling that "simply wrong" isn't quite right either. There *are* many contexts in which $0^0=1$ *is* the standard convention.

Two examples. First, power series. If we say $f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n$ that's supposed to entail that $f(0)=a_0$. But $f(0)=a_0$ depends on the convention that $0^0=1$.

Second, elementary set theory: Say $|A|$ is the cardinality of $A$. The cardinality of the set off all functions from $A$ to $B$ should be $|B|^{|A|}$. Now what if $A=B=\emptyset$? There as well we want to say $0^0=1$; otherwise we could just say the cardinality of the set of all maps was $|B|^{|A|}$ *unless* $A$ and $B$ are both empty.

(Yes, there *is* exactly one function $f:\emptyset\to\emptyset$...)

**Edit:** Seems to be a popular answer, but I just realized that it really doesn't address what the OP said. For the record, of course the OP is nonetheless wrong in claiming to have *proved* that $0^0=1$. It's often left undefined, and in any case one does not *prove* definitions...

Comment: Indeed, it's called an [Empty Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_function).

Comment: To add to the answer, OP only proves that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x$ is consistent with $0^0=1$; but it doesn't mean something else can't be inconsistent with $0^0=1$ (and indeed $\lim_{x\to 0^+}0^x=0\neq 1$).

Answer (score 1):

The limit of the function $y^x$ at $[0,0]$ does not exist. In fact it depends on the path used to approach $0$.

$0^0$ is **defined** to be $1$.

Comment: Sometimes it's left undefined.

Comment: E.g., WolframAlpha leaves it undefined. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%5E0

Answer (score 1):

As user72694 and addy2012 point out, here is an example for which $f(x) \neq g(x)$.

Consider

$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \left( e^{-t}\right)^\frac{1}{t} \to 0^0$$

But

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \left( e^{-t}\right)^\frac{1}{t} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \left( e^{-t \frac{1}{t}}\right) = \lim_{t \to \infty} \left( e^{-1} \right) = \frac{1}{e} \neq 1$$

Answer (score 0):

As I think you correctly guessed, one considers the quantities to be tending to zero independently when one works with an indeterminate form, including the one of type $0^0$.  If they are the same you indeed get 1, otherwise the answer may vary.

Answer (score 0):

$0^0=1$ is a convention. You can nevertheless justify it by $$0^0=|\mathcal F(\emptyset, \emptyset)|=1$$
since $|\mathcal F(A,B)|=|B|^{|A|}$ if $|A|,|B|<\infty $.

But you have other "proof" that justify this convention. For exemple, for extending the fact that $a^0=1$ for all $a\in \mathbb R$ (i.e. prolonge $x\longmapsto x^0$ to $1$ in $x=0$ by continuity).

However, you can also make the convention that $0^0=0$ (depending on the context), but it's not often used.

I recall that $\mathcal F(A,B)=\{f:A\longrightarrow B\mid f\text{ is a function}\}$.

Comment: There is no need to prove that $0^0 = 1$ because this follows directly from the definition $x^n = x \cdots x$ ($n$ $x$'s) and the empty product rule.

Answer (score -1):

In [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3h1132984p5312182), I wrote a detailed explanation on why $0^0=1$ is *convenient* to use, and why $0^0$ is undefined.

Copying the text, we have

1. Write a polynomial, for example $x^3-5x^2+7x+2$.
   If we write this polynomial as $x^3-5x^2+7x^1+2x^0$, it will give consistency and make it easier to deal with certain notations.
2. We have that $\lim_{x\to 0+}x^x = 1$
   This can be proven easily by taking the natural log and applying L'Hopital's Rule.
3. From $\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^n\right) = nx^{n-1}$, set $n=1$.
   This gives that $1 = x^{0}$. Now plug in $x=0$, giving $0^0=1$.
4. How many functions $f : X \rightarrow Y$ are there if $X = Y = \phi$?
   There is only one such function. Also the number of functions is given by $0^0$ as well, which means that $0^0=1$.

Now for reasons that $0^0$ is still undefined, copying the text again,

1. Cauchy, who is a pioneer of analysis, wrote in 1821 that $0^0$ is undefined.
2. Libri, in 1830, wrote a paper that "proved" $0^0=1$, which was very flawed.
   Few years later, Mobius wrote a paper in support of Libri, and claimed the following.

If $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x) = 0$, we have $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)^{g(x)} = 1$.

This was disproved by a mathematician, with its counterexample being $f(x)=a^{-\frac{1}{x}}, g(x)=x$ for $a>1$.

Again, as noted [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3h1132984p5313552), it is convention to leave $0^0$ as undefined.

Of course, in combinatorics, it's very useful to leave (and define) $0^0=1$.

Comment: Indeed any power series gives the same example. I didn't notice that when I wrote the post on AoPS four months ago :(

Comment: Cauchy did not write that $0^0$ is undefined, the history is more subtle than that.  He did include it in a list of "indeterminate forms" but it is hard to draw an unambiguous conclusion from that due to the lack of a formal definition.

Limit arguments are irrelevant unless one accepts the "continuity rule" that you may only define $f(p)$ if $f$ is continuous at $p$. This unstated but implicitly used rule, combined with Cauchy's results, led to the conclusion that $0^0$ should be left undefined. However, by now this rule has been abandoned over a century ago.