# What is $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^0$?

Tags: limits

What is $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^0$$?
Would this equal to $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x^x = 1$?

If the limit is undefined, would $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} x^0$ be defined?

Comment: what is this question? $x^0 = 1$ as x approaches 0 $x^0$ is equal to 1

Comment: Excellent discussion of different viewpoints here http://www.askamathematician.com/2010/12/q-what-does-00-zero-raised-to-the-zeroth-power-equal-why-do-mathematicians-and-high-school-teachers-disagree/

Comment: @Richard I dislike this opening sentence for the mathematicians side: "Zero raised to the zero power is one. Why? Because mathematicians said so. No really, it’s true." There are solid *reasons* mathematicians choose to define it as $1$. In particular, when dealing with natural numbers, it makes absolute and simple sense to define $x^y$ inductively as $x^0=1$ and $x^{n+1}=x\cdot x^n$. To leave $0^0$ undefined leads to complexity that is pointless. Also, all empty products are $1$, again, because that is the simplest definition. An sequence of no $0$s is no different from a sequence of no 2s.

Comment: @Richard This question is not about $0^0$. But it's natural to remark on the latter anyway, so I'll refer to [Zero to the zero power - Is $0^0=1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/) which offers an explanation that's both more transparent and more concise.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I agree there are good reasons, but it has not consistently been the mathematicians choice. I recently read a paper on from less than 20 years ago that addressed the argument. The webpage gives some of the reasons for the current near consensus near the end of the article. For me, the binomial theorem was very persuasive evidence that it is the correct choice.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034654/0-to-the-power-of-0-what-does-the-essential-discontinuity-actually-look-like/) question is relevant; I proved that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}x^{\alpha x}=1$ in my answer to it.

Comment: Lots of people telling me about stuff they've read, nobody making an actual argument. @Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(i)
$$\lim_{x \to 0} x^0 = 1$$

because $a^0 = 1$ for any $a \neq 0$. But with the limit, we are considering the neighborhood of $0$, and not $0$ itself.

(ii)

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x = \exp \left( \lim_{x \to 0^+} x \log x \right) \stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{=} \exp(0)=1
.$$

Comment: log 0 is not defined I think.

Answer (score 5):

$x^0=1$ for all $x$, in particular for $x\neq 0$. So this is the same as $\lim_{x\to 0} 1 = 1$.

$x^x$ is not well-defined on any $(-\delta,\delta)\setminus\{0\}$, so you have to be careful. $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x$ does exist.

Comment: But isn't $0^0$ indeterminate? So it's not true that for all $x$, $x^0 =1$...

Comment: But you are not considering $0^0$. The limit explains the behavior around the neighborhood of the point, but not at the point exactly.

Comment: Indeterminate does not mean undefined. It just means that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} x^y$ does not exist. We use $x^0=1$ all the time in mathematics - for example, when we write $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ for a polynomial and say $p(0)=a_0$.

Comment: In particular, in lambda calculus and set theory definitions of $x^y$, we get $0^0=1$ unless we go out of our way to say it is undefined. You get no contradiction by defining $0^0=1$, and we use it quite a bit, so we define it that way. We just have to remember that the function $x^y$ is not continuous there. @limito

Comment: I occasionally define addition so that $1+1 = 0$. That does not mean addition is ambiguous: it means that there are two different notions of addition that I am prone to using. The only ambiguity is which notion of addition I mean when I write $+$. It's the same deal with $0^0$.

Comment: @Hurkyl True, but we actually use $0^0=1$ implicitly quite often. It is almost always pointless to make it undefined, as long as we recognize the discontinuity.

Comment: The first sentence would leave less room to doubt (and follow-up questions in comments) if it said "$x^0=1$ for $x\ne 0$". The value of $0^0$ is an issue that occupies a [whole other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/11150/147263) on this site, and it's *not relevant* here.

Comment: True, but that would perpetuate misinformation (it wouldn't actually be wrong, just imply a common misconception.) @Behaviour

Answer (score 1):

$$x^0=1$$was based on the assumption that $x\neq 0$ and only then  we could show that $$\frac{x^m}{x^m}=x^{m-m}=x^0=1$$
 Therefore since when x goes to 0 x is never 0 then $x^0$goes to 1.

Comment: $x^y=\exp(y \ln x)$ for $x > 0$ and $y \in \mathbb R$

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} x^0 = 1 $$

because **anything** to the zero power will equal 1.

/edit

$\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x$ does exist.

Comment: You mean **anything** $\neq 0$?

Comment: But $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x$ does exist. It equals one. Use Log-Exp technique to see this from right hand side.

Comment: Yes, @Bot is wrong about the limit of $x^x$. Not clear why he put quotes around "exist," there.

Comment: I'm very skeptical about $0^0$, there was a big thread about this a few days ago with other indeterminate forms and the general consensus was that it was undefined ... ?

Comment: The general consensus is wrong. Mathematicians define it as $1$. Sorry if that bugs you, but that is the definition. Again, see my comments below.

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with that. Anyhow, I have up voted your answer regardless. I think you did a better job answering it then I did.

Comment: @GabrielH Find me a mathematician who is not talking about estimates for reals numbers (where $0$ really means an interval containing $0$) who leaves $0^0$ undefined. It really shouldn't be hard. I've pointed out several ways that we implicitly define $0^0$ for natural numbers, and why we do so. (An empty list of $0$s is no different from an empty list of $3$s, so $0^0=3^0$.)

Comment: (And no, calling it indeterminate is not the same as calling it undefined.)

Comment: Okay, can we settle on $0^0 \ge \le 1$ where $\ge \le$ denotes *maybe*? :-)

Comment: Nope, it is equal to $1$.

Comment: I'm just messing with you. Okay, okay, $0^0 = 1$. On the record.