# How to derive $\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow 0} x^0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

In [What is $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080362/what-is-lim-x-rightarrow-0-x0)

There are discussion that the number is 1.

Of course $ 0^{0} $ isn't well defined.  $ 0^{x} $ is $0$ and $ x^{0} $ is always 1 for all $x\neq 0$

I'd say the limit will either be 1 or $0$ depending on how we approach it. It seems that if we approach it from $ x^{x} $

However, I want simple proofs.

One proof says that

$ \lim_\limits{x \rightarrow 0}  x^{x} = \lim_\limits{x \rightarrow 0}   e^{\log( x^{x})}   $

$= \lim_\limits{x \rightarrow 0} e^{\log( x^{x})}$

$= e^{\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow 0} \log( x^{x})}$

$= e^{\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow 0} x \cdot \log(x)}$

I am stuck here. That's because $\log(0)$ is not well defined either. So how to show that it's 1?

Comment: as $x≠0$, $x^0=1$. You probably asked for $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} x^x =1$

Comment: Usually, $0^0$ is **defined** as $1$ as that turns out to be a useful definition in most cases. It is $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x^y$ that does not exist.

Comment: @robjohn .......Out of curiosity, could you name such instances where this definition is used

Comment: To name two, power series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$ and binomial expansions $(1+x)^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k$. In both of these, $0^0=1$ is assumed. To name another, when counting functions from $A$ to $B$, we get $|B|^{|A|}$ and when $A=B=\emptyset$, we have $0^0=1$, the empty function.

Comment: $x^x$ is completely irrelevant if you want to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}x^0$. $x^0$ is not the same function as $x^x$, so why should they have the same limit? $x^0=1$ for all $x\ne 0$, so the limit is unambiguously $1$.

Comment: @TonyK: I think the confusion is that in a lot of places, it is said that $0^0$ is not well-defined because $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x^y$ does not exist. I think a lot of weakly-founded questions (I'm not saying this one is or is not one of them), are posed because of this confusion. Some may think that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x^x$ is the same thing.

Comment: @robjohn: yes, of course. The intent of my comment was to impress on the OP that the limit under discussion is not a question of _opinion_; it is well defined and simple to evaluate.

Comment: Perhaps I should move the rant to my answer. I have [posted before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/488920) regarding [$0^0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1032304) and [$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x^y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1755230). It will remain a topic here, even if it does appear [in the FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11150).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zero to the zero power – is $0^0=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument you are trying to use can be finished by setting
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} x^x
 = \exp\left( \lim_{x \to 0} x \ln(x) \right)
 = \exp\left( \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln x}{1/x} \right)
 \overset{*}{=}
   \exp\left( \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1/x}{1/x^2} \right)
 = e^0 = 1,
$$
where step (*) follows by L'Hospital's rule.

---

However, if you are seeking to define $0^0$, note that this may be achieved in a variety of forms. You are choosing
$$
0^0 := \lim_{x \to 0} x^x = 1,
$$
but other forms could be chosen, with
$$
0^0 := \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)^{g(x)},
$$
as long as both $f,g \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, potentially giving a different result.

Comment: Sorry I did not see u answered it

Comment: @NamburuKarthik I just edited to finish the argument for you...

Comment: He did. L'hospital rule is the key. I didn't know that

Comment: I think you should make it more explicit. You change x ln(x) into ln(x)/(1/x)

Comment: @user4951 I thought I did, but rewrote to make it explicit. Hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

For $x$ near $0$ (but not in $0$) it is $x^0=1$ (as @Alapan Das commented).

So $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x^0=\lim\limits_{x\to0}1=1$

Answer (score 2):

First of all, $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x^0=\lim\limits_{x\to0}1=1$. On the other hand, we can use the series for $\log(1-x)$ to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}x^x$:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}x\log(x)
&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\,(1-x)\log(1-x)\tag1\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{x\to1^-}(x-1)\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}k\tag2\\
&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\left(-x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty x^k\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right)\right)\tag3\\
&=-1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right)\tag4\\[3pt]
&=-1+1\tag5\\[12pt]
&=0\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto1-x$
$(2)$: use the series for $\log(1-x)$
$(3)$: multiply the series by $x-1$
$(4)$: take the limit
$(5)$: telescoping sum
$(6)$: simplify

Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}x^x=1\tag7
$$