# Taylor Series for $x^2 \ln(1 + \frac{1}{x})$ at $x = 0$.

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

We know that the Taylor Series of a function, grade $n$ at $x = a$ is given by $$ P_{n,a}(x) = a_0 + a_1(x-a) + a_2(x-a)^2 + ... + a_n(x-a)^n $$ where $ a_i = \frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!} $.

The problem that I have is that when I try to make the first term of the Taylor Series of $f(x) = x^2 \ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$, I get $$ \frac{0^2 \ln(1+\frac{1}{0})}{0!} $$ but that I can't do $\frac{1}{0}$.

Then, I have to use its Taylor Series to evaluate $$  \lim_{x \to 0} [x - x^2\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})]$$

Comment: The function is not even defined at $x=0$, so you can't talk about a Taylor series. Did you rephrase the question in your own words, or is this exactly how the question was asked?

Comment: The problem says that I have to make the limit, using the Taylor Series formula.

Comment: Ah in that case, take a look at the hint provided below (also, in the future, be sure to ask the actual question first, rather than at the end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

For $x>0$,

$$\ln(1+\frac 1x)=\ln(1+x)-\ln(x)$$
and

$$\ln(1+x)=x+x\epsilon(x)$$
with
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\epsilon(x)=0$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln(x)=0$$

Comment: What does the $\epsilon(x)$ stands for?

Comment: @SocietyViper The rest in Taylor-Youg formula.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $ x \ln x \rightarrow 0$ for $x \rightarrow 0+$. Now, close to the origin

$$
f(x) = x^2(\ln(x+1) -\ln(x)) \approx x^3 -x^2 \ln x 
$$

This is sufficient to say that $f \rightarrow 0$. Therefore, also your last limit is zero.

Answer (score 0):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3683950), the power series for $\log(1+x)$ is used to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}x\log(x)=0\tag1
$$
Therefore, since $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\log(1+x)=0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}x^2\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}x^2\left(\log(1+x)-\log(x)\right)\tag2\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}x^2\log(1+x)-\lim_{x\to0^+}x^2\log(x)\tag3\\
&=0-0\tag4
\end{align}
$$
However, the second derivative does not exist at $x=0$:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}x^2\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)
=2\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)-\frac{3+2x}{(1+x)^2}
$$
so there can't be a Taylor expansion there.