# When is $0^{0}=0$ useful?

Tags: soft-question

Are there mathematical areas/situations in which defining $0^{0}$ as $0$ is useful/sensible and convention (in contrast to the "common" definition as $1$) ?

Comment: Cheeky answer: How about in the zero ring?

Comment: Even in the zero ring, it's still basically 1, but now the multiplicative identity is the same as the additive identity.

Comment: I cannot think of any such situation. You may be interested in reading through the reasons why $0^0$ is commonly taken as $1$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1/1223061#1223061). Depending on context, it is taken to be either $1$, indeterminate or undefined/nonexistent; but never $0$.

Comment: @jgon That's why I said it was the cheeky answer.

Comment: @Mufasa Because I read those reasons I asked myself if there was any context as described above @ others: Very interesting! Never heard of it before as I'm still in school

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $p$-norm is a generalization of the standard Euclidean norm for vectors. [It is defined as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#p-norm):

$${\parallel\mathbf{x}\parallel}_p = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \left|x_i\right|^p\right)^{1/p}$$

This is for $p > 0$. What about $p = 0$?

Well, maybe we can call that the $0$-norm. The $0$-norm, is very useful in measuring the "sparsity" of a vector. A vector is $s$-sparse if only $s$ of its components are non-zero. It's useful to have $0^0$ be defined as $0$, while any other $r^0$ (where $r \neq 0$) is $1$. Okay, so the $0$ norm is not *quite* a $p$-norm (because we drop the $1/p$, but it is analogous. Actually, the zero norm is not even a [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Definition) (it's not scalable). Oops.

Anyway, so the $\ell_0$-norm (the common name for this measurement), for measuring the sparsity of a vector, looks something like:

$$ {\parallel\mathbf{x}\parallel}_0 = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \left|x_i\right|^0\right)$$

Why is sparsity a big deal? Well, [compressed sensing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_sensing) is one good reason why.

Basically, compressed sensing tells us that under certain conditions (the signal is sparse, and the sensing matrix is randomly distributed), we can reconstruct a signal with even less information than is required by Nyquist-Shannon theorem.