# Is $\log(\aleph_0)$ undefined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

NOTE: In the context of this question, the base of $\log(x)$ is $10$.

I was researching cardinal arithmetic when I found out about logarithms of infinite cardinal numbers. Assuming the axiom of choice and given a infinite cardinal $κ$ and a finite cardinal $μ$ greater than 1, there may or may not exist a cardinal $λ$ which satisfies $μ^κ=λ$. If $λ$ does exist, then it is infinite and less than $κ$.

Since $\aleph_0$ is the smallest infinite cardinal number, $λ$ cannot exist, so does that mean $\log(\aleph_0)$ is undefined?

Comment: It is not undefined, because there is a definition. However, as you said, it is proven that there is no cardinal number verifying this definition. I'm not sure what would be the correct term in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the logarithm of $\aleph_0$ infinite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280901/is-the-logarithm-of-aleph-0-infinite)

Comment: Given $μ>1$ and $κ>2$ (both finite or infinite) then $μ^κ$ always exists and $μ^κ>κ$

Comment: @QuinnLesquimau the correct term is undefined, just like I can define division, and get that division by 0 is undefined

Comment: For certain purposes the logarithm of an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ is sometimes defined to be the least cardinal $\lambda$ such that $2^\lambda\ge\kappa$. According to that definition $\log\aleph_0=\aleph_0$. (Using $10$ instead of $2$ as the base would not make any difference but seems really quaint.)

Comment: @bof  But that would mean $\aleph_0 < \aleph_0$, which doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @MathGeek No it doesn't mean $\aleph_0\lt\aleph_0$, why do you think that? Note that this definition says $2^{\log\kappa}\ge\kappa$, **not** $2^{\log\kappa}=\kappa$.

Comment: By the way I found that definition on p. 74 of *Cardinal Functions in Topology* by I. Juhász.

Comment: Note that the logarithm function defined this way is nonstrictly increasing: $\log\aleph_0=\log\aleph_1=\log2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @bof Hi! I asked Wolfram Alpha to find the value of $\log2^{\aleph_0}$, but it said that $\log2^{\aleph_0}$ is undefined. Is this true?

Comment: Defined by whom? Some people find it usefil to define it the way I told you, others don't. Juhász does; evidently Wolfram Alpha doesn't. Mathematics is an anarchy; there is no official body to tell everyone what definitions they must use. It's not like astronomy where the IAU claims the authority to legislate the definition of a "planet". Most mathematicians have no use for logs of infinite cardinals. I've just told how how they are used by one small band of specialists, the "set-theoretic topologists", or at least some of them.

Comment: Added to @bof's comment, when people say things like "$0/0$ is undefined", all they mean is that mathematicians generally agree that there is more useful to not define $0/0$ than to define $0/0$. I can define $0/0$ as $5$ if I want to. Then, the symbol "$0/0$" would have exactly the same meaning as the symbol "$5$". But this definition wouldn't be consistent with the usual meaning of division, and so few people would find this definition useful. A symbol being "defined" or "undefined" is not an intrinsic property of that symbol, but a matter of **convention**.

Comment: @bof I understand. However, if we say that $\log\aleph_1=\log2^{\aleph_0}$, then we are effectively saying that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$, which means the continuum hypothesis is correct.

Comment: @MathGeek: By the same reasoning, if $5^2=(-5)^2$, then $5=-5$.

Comment: @MathGeek We would if we defined $\log\kappa$ as "the number $\lambda$ such that $2^\lambda=\kappa$." But the definition I'm referring to defines $\log\kappa$ as "the least number $\lambda$ such that $2^\lambda$ is GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO $\kappa$." I think I mentioned this before. It's really an extension of the function $\lceil\log x\rceil$ to infinite cardinals.

Comment: @bof Do the laws of logarithms work with infinite cardinals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think $\log \aleph_0$ exists.

An easy way to see this is that if we denote the power set of $\mathbb A$ as $2^\mathbb A$, then there is no cardinal $\mathbb X$ such that $\aleph_0=2^\mathbb X$ because $\aleph_0$ is the smallest cardinal by definition. So, there is no cardinal $\mathbb X$ such that $\log \aleph_0=\mathbb X$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't exist because,

Let, $X=\operatorname{log}(\aleph_0)$

$\aleph_0=10^X$

If, $X\lt\aleph_0$

Then, $10^X\lt\aleph_0$

So, $X\not\lt\aleph_0$

And if, $X\geq\aleph_0$

Then, $10^X\geq 10^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}\geq\aleph_1\gt\aleph_0$

So, $X\not\geq\aleph_0$

This leads us to the only conclusion that, $\textstyle\displaystyle{X\in\emptyset}$.

So, $\operatorname{log}(\aleph_0)$ cannot exist.