# what is the value of 0^0?

Tags: calculus

I know the value of 0^0 depend on the direction that we take the limit.
But, I dont know how this fact assert 0^0 doesn't exist. 
I think they say just limit of 0^0 doen't exist. 
I'm so confused.

Comment: $0^0$ is not well-defined.

Comment: [Zero to the zero power](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1)

Comment: https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14709220/Zero-puissance-zero-Zero-to-the-Zero-th-Power