# What is 0^0 ?? 0, 1 or not defined

Tags: logic

What is the value of $0^0$ ??

I have read many discussions regarding it but the result was only confusion.
Is it 0, 1 or **not defined**??

Comment: This has been asked before.

Comment: This has been asked many times before, but it's difficult to search for. Could someone find an appropriate duplicate thread so we can close this one?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1

Comment: See the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1).  In brief, $0^0$ is either $1$ or undefined, depending on the context.  It is rarely, if ever, defined to be zero.

Comment: Amusingly, Google reports more than 25 billion results if you search on "0^0."  Its own calculator says the answer is $1$.

Comment: I find the fascination with $0^0$ very curious, as there are few situations in which it arises in any context. Up there with summing positive numbers to $-{1 \over 12}$ - more evidence of the conspiratorial nature of mathematics.

Comment: @copper.hat What do you mean by conspiratorial?

Comment: @user3491648: It was a lighthearted poke at the fascination many have with proofs of $1 = 0$, etc. As though it was evidence of some deep flaw that mathematicians conspire to hide from the rest :-).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to 0^0 = not defined. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRRolKTlF6Q
explains it with more detail.