# The value of $0^n$

Tags: calculus, arithmetic, exponentiation

In an attempt to compute $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^k {n\choose k}}$ the author put $x=-1$ in the formula $(x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{ {n\choose k}x^k  }$

Then he wrote that we have
$$0^n = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } n \in \mathbb N^* \\
1 & \mbox{if } n =0 \end{cases}  $$

How is that done and is the function $0^n$ defined at all?
I mean my understanding is that $0^n=e^{n\log0}$ but $\log 0$ is not defined at all. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think, the tag should be extended to "reference request". For such a basic question there should be an entry in any handbook of number theory...

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1

Comment: Don't forget that $x^n=x\cdot x\cdots x$, hence no problem with $n>0$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $x^y$ has a discontinuity at $(0, 0)$. If you take $x = 0$ and $y > 0$, it is $0$; for $x > 0$ and $y = 0$ it is $1$. No way around it. Just be careful.

Now, you can write a polynomial (and power series) as:

$$
a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \dotsb
$$

This can be written:

$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
$$

as then the term $a_0 z^0 = a_0$ works out nicely *unless $z = 0$*. To avoid awkward formulæ, in such kinds of uses the *convention* that $0^0 = 1$ is adopted.

So, one take is that $0^n = 0$ unless $n = 0$, when it is $1$. Or you could say $0^0 = 0$ to make it continuous on the exponent. Or bite the bullet and declare it isn't defined at all. Take you pick, according to convenience.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of definitions. For a polynomial $p(x)\neq 0$ (in general, for an element $a\neq 0$ of some ring) we have $p(x)^0=1$, so that the relation $p(x)^mp(x)^n=p(x)^{m+n}$ holds true for $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$.