# Two numbers equality formula

Tags: functions

Given two real numbers $a$ and $b$, is there any formula which would give $1$ if $a=b$ and $0$ if not ? 
(I am not talking about conditional expressions).
Thanks.

Edit : Everything is allowed.

Comment: Depends on the allowed functions: $1-\mathrm{sign}|a-b|$ is one solution.

Comment: It's rather obvious that no continuous function $f(a,b)$ will do (thus a function that uses only polynomials or absolute value can't work), so there must be some hidden conditional in the definition of $f$ or a limiting process. Hence, you should clarify what is allowed and what is not.

Comment: Everything is allowed (Preferably trigonometric functions)

Comment: @Weber Trigonometric functions alone can't work, as they are either continuous (sine, cosine) or not defined everyhere (tangent). In the latter case, you will end up with a function that is not defined everywhere either, thus can't work on all cases. In the former, it's continuous, whereas your function is not. Thus, either you hide the conditional (sign) either you "push the discontinuity to infinity" with a limit.

Comment: If you dont mind having infinite number of trignometric terms, you can use fourier series representation of the delta function.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Feel free to suggest anything.

Comment: Just curious, what is your motivation behind this question?

Comment: @JiK I am a programmer and I am trying to leverage some heavy algorithms by mathematical shortcut functions

Comment: @ L16H7 Would you give an example using  Fourier series ?

Comment: @Weber It's really easy to use a Fourier series : take the sign function on [-1,1], complete by periodicity, compute its Fourier series $S(x)$ and compute $1-|S(2/\pi \arctan(b-a))|$.

Comment: $$\left\lfloor\frac1{(a-b)^2+1}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Why are explicit conditionals excluded from "everything"? They're an entirely natural way to write things like this, and functions expressed with conditionals aren't somehow "cheating" or "unmathematical".

Comment: @user2357112 As I said before, I am  a programmer and explicit conditionals are what I am already using in my code. Now I want to make use of some math formulas to reduce processing time.

Comment: @Weber: Why do you think explicit conditionals are hurting your performance? An explicit conditional is just as much of a "math formula" as any answer you've received, many of which would be implemented with conditionals anyway. And what language are you working in? In a lot of languages, `a == b` is *already* 1 if they're equal and 0 otherwise.

Comment: @user2357112 It's not a == b that I am trying to optimize , but rather a big chunk of my algorithm will be transformed  to a math function. The question I asked about the equality is just a step needed to complete the transformation.

Comment: @Weber: Are you trying to get an expression that you can simplify? It's not clear what you mean by having a big chunk of your algorithm "transformed into a math function", or why that would provide any performance benefit.

Comment: @user2357112 Here is a simple example : Imagine you want to find the sum of the first n natural numbers, so the naif implementation would be  (for(int i =1 ;i<=n; i++) S += i;) now compare that algorithm with the equivalent math formula ( S =  (n+n^2)/2) . try to execute both codes for n = 1000000 or more !

Comment: @Weber: Now we're getting somewhere. What you want isn't a "math formula"; you're looking for a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression). Unfortunately, there aren't really any useful transformations you can apply to `a == b`. All the answers you've gotten are notational differences or ways to complicate things. None of this will help you; you need to analyze your problem from a higher-level perspective.

Comment: @user2357112 You are right about the closed form, I wonder if we can find a systematic method to transform any algorithm  to a closed form.

Comment: @Weber: Nope. A lot of work has gone into noping that from a variety of directions, such as the halting problem and the time hierarchy theorem.

Comment: Weber, if you are just trying to optimize code, then either use conditionals, or use specific assembly instructions (like `sete` or `cmove` on x86). None of the formulas below is likely to be faster.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut A whelk's chance in a supernova.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(It's taken me long enough to write this ... I bet some of these appear in other answers.)

- Using the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket):  $[a=b]$
- Using the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) (not typically used for reals, except when defining discrete distributions): $\delta_{a b}$
- Using [contour integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration) (sneakily): $ \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(a-b)\theta/n} \,\mathrm{d}\theta$
- Using the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function): $\mathbf{1}_{\{a\}}(b)$
- Using a standard not [uniformly continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity) (on $[0,1]$) sequence of functions:  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\min\{a/b,b/a\})^n $
- Using the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) (in disguise, using the Fourier result that the value at the jump is the mean of the limits from each side): $\left. 4(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \max\{x,0\})(1-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \max\{x,0\}) \right|_{x = a-b}$
- Using the [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions):  $1 - \lceil \frac{|a-b|}{|a-b|+1} \rceil$

Edit:  Because, of course, one has to get the parity of the last one backwards.  Fixed.

Edit:  Added limit to contour integral because, sadly, not all pairs of reals have integer differences.  And more:

- We can look at the [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function) of a certain [cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) function:  $\lim_{A \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2A} \int_{-A}^A \cos((a-b)x) \,\mathrm{d}x$
- We can use the [sine integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral):  $1-\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\frac{2}{N\pi} \sum_{n=0}^N \mathrm{Si}(n \, |a-b|)$
- Iteration:  $f^{[1]}(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $ f^{[n]}(x) = f^{[n-1]} \circ f^{[1]}(x)$.  Compute $1-\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f^{[n]}(|a-b|)$.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Iverson bracket. Those little braces have made many an expression more efficient, more readable and generally beautiful.

Comment: Well done, but some of your suggestions are “conditional expressions.”

Comment: It seems to me that the contour integral one only works for integers.

Comment: These are all wonderful... it should be noted for OP that in terms of computation, all of these are waaaaay harder for a computer to perform than a single "==" check

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld :  D'oh.  Umm...  All reals are integers, right?  :-)

Answer (score 11):

The classic one: $0^{|a-b|}$ ...

Edit: In case you consider $|.|$ as conditional choose $$0^\sqrt{(a-b)^2}$$
instead.

Comment: Could this one be expressed in another form so the zero is not there any more ?

Comment: @Weber : $\: (1\hspace{-0.05 in}-\hspace{-0.05 in}1)^{\hspace{.02 in}|\hspace{.02 in}a-b|} \;\;\;\;$

Comment: @Ricky I mean something that doesn't evaluate directly to zero.

Comment: @Weber How could you possibly write this in another form without a term that evaluates directly to zero?  What do you mean by 'expressed in another form'?

Comment: Why not just $0^{(a-b)^2}$? The square root is unnecessary. @Weber

Comment: Wait $0^0$ is 1? I thought it's undefined...

Comment: @TomášZato [It's technically undefined, but often defined as 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/11155/118470).

Comment: How about $\lim_{x \to 0} x^{(a-b)^2}$ to get around the undefinedness of $0^0$

Answer (score 6):

This one would do, if you allow limits:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \exp (-n|a-b|)$$

You could also compute

$$2-\mathrm{Card} \;\{a,b\}$$

Or

$$1-\int_{a-b}^{e(a-b)} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}$$

but I don't think it's very clean to rely on $\int_0^0 f(x) \mathrm dx=0$ when $f$ is not defined at $x=0$.

Another limit: taking $\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan (b-a)$ you get a number in $]-1,1[$, hence you can use the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1-x^2)^n$, which is $1$ if $x=0$ and $0$ if $x\in [-1,1]\backslash\{0\}$. All in all:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[1-\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan (a-b)\right)^2\right]^n$$

Answer (score 4):

You can use this function:
$||sgn(b-a)|-1|$

Answer (score 4):

How about this where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor function of $x$:

$\min\{\left\lfloor 2^x\right\rfloor, \left\lfloor 2^{-x}\right\rfloor\}$.

You can even get rid of the min function by recasting this as

$\frac{\left\lfloor 2^x\right\rfloor+ \left\lfloor 2^{-x}\right\rfloor-\mid \left\lfloor 2^x\right\rfloor- \left\lfloor 2^{-x}\right\rfloor\mid}{2}$

---

Edit: As ASKASK correctly pointed out (thanks), the question asked for an indicator of equality between $a$ and $b$ rather than an input of $x$ being $0$.  To make the adjustment, $x$ in the post can be replaced by $a-b$.

Comment: I think you should at least mention that we are plugging $x=a-b$ into this formula as OP seemed to request a formula in terms of $a$ and $b$

Comment: But otherwise, I really like this formula. To me it seems to be the cleanest.

Answer (score 4):

$\left\lfloor\frac{1}{1+(a-b)^2}\right\rfloor$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ - [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) and $a$ and $b$ - real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\left|\{a\}\cap\{b\}\right|
$$

Where $|\cdot|$ denotes the order (number of elements) of a set.

One can come up with many similar examples.  For example, $\left|\{(a,b)\}\cap\Delta\right|$, where $\Delta=\{(x,x)\;\colon\;x\in\mathbb R\}\subset\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

$\operatorname{sinc}(a\pi-b\pi)$ works for when $a$ and $b$ are integers.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this, but it maybe it is already too *conditinal* for you:

The indicator function is often used in such cases, so the function takes only two values, $0,1$ in such a way that
$$
1_M(x)=\begin{cases}0,x\text{ is not element of } M \\1,x\text{ is element of } M \end{cases}
$$
where M is any set which we choose. So in your case we would take $\{a\}:=M\subset\mathbb{R}$ and get
$$
1_{\{a\}}(x)=\begin{cases}0,x\text{ is not element of } \{a\} \\1,x\text{ is element of } \{a\} \end{cases}
$$
meaning $1_{\{a\}}(x)$ equals only $1$ if and only if $x=a$ or in you case 
 $1_{\{a\}}(b)=1$ with $b=a$. Although technically it actually says that it is only an element of an $1$-element set.

Comment: As I have said in my question, I am not talking about conditional expressions.

Comment: @Weber I know you did...but then I wasn't sure exactly what you by this, for example $\operatorname{sgn}(\cdot)$ or floor/ceil function are off the limits as well?

Comment: All functions are allowed, even integer ones.

Comment: @Weber I got this, I just meant that the above function I gave is as conditional as $\operatorname{sgn}(\cdot)$,ceil/floor functions are - so if you are satisfied with those, you might also take the indicator function into consideration

Answer (score 0):

Just this:
$$ \{a=b\} $$

It evaluates to 1 if the condition inside the curly brackets is true and to 0 if it isn't.

Comment: This is the Iverson bracket; square braces $[\cdot]$ are normally used, though.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Hmm, I don't know, it may be different in different countries

Comment: It's not _nearly_ old enough for that to happen. Iverson died in 2004, and Knuth is still around. (Iverson introduced it in his programming language APL, but with regular parentheses; Knuth started using it outside of programming, and changed it to square brackets to avoid ambiguity with the grouping parentheses already used in logic.)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger It is possible that we're talking about different things here. I originally meant this expression to be the type of the one used in [here](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/SoftmaxRegression/) near the middle of the page, "Cost Function" section