# How to prove that $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$, $f(x)=x^x$ is one to one and not onto

Tags: functions, proof-verification

I tried to solve it by first showing that the function is monotonically increasing which shows that it is one to one. Then finding a number that lies between two consecutive values of the function.

1)$f(x+k)=(x+k)^{(x+k)} > x^{x+k} > x^x$(by binomial theorem) when $k$ is a natural number greater than or equal to one.

2) $2^2<5<3^3$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: If it is defined on $\mathbf Z$, its  range is not contained in $\mathbf N$…

Comment: You are right, does that make the very question obsolete ?

Comment: @Jinn It means that the question as written does not make any sense. However, we can just assume you meant the range to be $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If you suppose the domain is $\mathbf N$, it's not  meaningless

Comment: @6005: You're right, but the answer is obvious then.

Comment: It would still be undefined at $0$

Comment: @Bernard Ah yes, I see.

Comment: @Jinn Not necessarily. We can say $0^0 = 1$.

Comment: Isn't that undefined

Comment: @Jinn More often than not in discrete contexts it is defined to be $1$.

Comment: I would like to read about it, since it contradicts my present knowledge. Can you cite some references?

Comment: @Jinn You can read about it in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1). As you can see from the answers, it's often important to say it is undefined (an "indeterminate form") but it is also often important to define it as $1$. It depends on the context.

Comment: @Jinn The empty product is defined to be $1$. -- Also for cardinalities, $a^b$ is the number of maps from a set of cardinality $b$ to a set of cardinality $a$. -- Even to allow the notation $\sum_{k=0}^n a_kX^k$ for polynomials where $X$ is just a *symbol* makes the deifniion (anything)${}^0=1$ useful. -- It is just so that when extending $x^y$ to real numbers as far as one can, it is not possible to make the function *continuous* at $(0,0)$, but that is a whole differnt story than not being defined (after all the ways to defined powers *start* with naturals and are only *extended* to reals,

Comment: @6005 indeterminate $\ne $ undefined

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for the correction, I wasn't aware of that distinction (and it seems to only matter in the case of $0^0$, since all the other standard indeterminate forms are actually undefined, except maybe $0 \cdot \infty$ which is sometimes defined to be $0$.)

Comment: On second thought, $0 \cdot \infty$, $0^0$, $0^\infty$, $1^\infty$, and $\infty^0$ all have natural interpretations in set theory and combinatorics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not actually a function $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$.
If you want the function to be defined for negative integers, you need the codomain to be $\mathbb{Q}$. But then if it is defined for $0$ we would have $0^0 = 1 = 1^1$, so it wouldn't be one-to-one.

Therefore, let me assume you meant for the function to be $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, $f(x) = x^x$. Then your solution is correct! Since the function is strictly increasing ($f(x+k) > f(x)$) it is one-to-one, and since it skips $5$ it is not onto. Good work.