# What $T^0$ if $T \neq0$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Here in "linear algebra hoffman kunze" book it is given that if $T$ is a linear transformation on vector space $V$ then $T^n = T \ldots T $ ($n$ times) and they define $T^0=I$ if $T\neq0$ where $I$ is the identity transformation. I could not understand what is meant by $T \neq 0 $.

Comment: $T=0$ if it maps every element to $0$.

Comment: So, if it is given that $T=0$ then why $T^0\neq I$?

Comment: Probably just personal preference on the authors' part.

Comment: @Saikat I see no particular reason to make $T = 0$ an exception here, but it doesn't really make a difference.  The only thing worth remembering is that it's often convenient to define $T^0 = I$ (especially in power series of matrices).

Comment: They are not defining the $0^{\text{th}}$ power of the zero matrix.

Comment: @Lee Mosher How is zero matrix coming into picture?

Comment: @Saikat: How? The authors must have chosen, for their own ineffable reasons, to explicitly exclude it from their definition of $T^0$. We can't know _why_ they chose that without being them.

Comment: You usually make the same exception when you define $x^0=1$ for real numbers, and the same reasoning (almost) applies, so it should not be surprising.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well, there might be a good (and understandable by us) reason for that. However, if this is the case, we probably need more context (and then, the question of Saikat makes fully sense to me).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom there must a case where if we define "$T^o=I$" and  $T=0$ ,then there is some problem.

Comment: @Saikat there isn't one that I know of

Comment: @Omnomnomnom me neither, but isn't a proof that it doesn't exist :).

Comment: The zero matrix is the matrix representing the linear transformation $T=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $T:V \to V$, then $T = 0$ means that $T$ satisfies $T(v) = 0$ for every $v \in V$.

Comment: @HM fair point.  I might delete this answer at any rate, given the ensuing discussion above.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the authors define $T^{0}=I$ if $T \neq 0$, they want to express $T^{1}=T^{0}T=T$ and $T^{n}=T^{n-1}T$.

Comment: What is the problem in defining $T^{n}=T^{n-1}T$ if $T=0$ and $T^{0}=I$? Then, we have $T= 0\cdot I=0$ and $T^{n}=0$ for any $n>1$.

Comment: If $T\neq 0$, then $T=T^0T=IT=T$.

Comment: Yes and if $T=0$, then $T=T^0T=IT=0=T$.

Comment: Suppose that a linear transformation on vector space $V$ is a matrix $A$. Then $T^n=TT ...T$ (n times) is equivalent to be $A^n$.

Comment: @bing the question is *why did the author exclude $T=0$ from the definition*.

Comment: Oh,  $T=0$ is trivial. Your answer is right.

Comment: @bing If it would be trivial, there wouldn't be a need to exclude this case I guess.

Comment: @Surb No, if no exclude $T=0$, then $0^0=I$, this is ridiculous.

Comment: @bing Why is it *ridiculous*? If $T\colon V \to V$ and $V=\Bbb R^1$, then $T^0=0^0=1$ is a [commonly accepted convention](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1).

Comment: @Surb  $0: V \to V$ mean that $0(v)=0$ for any $v \in V$.