# What is zero to the power of zero? $0^0$

Tags: exponentiation

> Evaluate:
>   $$0^0$$

Would you use this law of indices?

> $$x^0=1$$

Or would you use that:

> $$\frac{x^n}{x^n}=x^0$$ which would mean $$\frac{0}{0}=undefined$$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I'd use $0^0=1$. Makes sense if you consider the function $x\mapsto x^x$ for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: This has been asked many times on this site. $0^0$ is undefined without being explicit. Most of the time, it's defined to be equal to $1$ for convenience, such as in the binomial theorem.