# Formula for number of apple pieces to number of slices made?

Tags: sequences-and-series

An apple can only be sliced through its center. When 0 slices have been made, the apple is in 1 piece. When 1 slice is made, the apple is in 2 pieces. When 2 slices are made, the apple is in 4 pieces. Find a formula to describe number of pieces the apple will be in when sliced $n$ times.

I have tried to do this problem. After 1 slice, the formula for the total number of pieces is $2n$. However, the formula does not work when n = 0. When $n = 0$, there is only 1 piece, so the formula does not work.

Is it impossible to find a formula for this question? I'm trying to find the number of exposed surfaces of an apple when cut n times through the center, but I cannot even seem to find a formula for this basic problem.

Comment: it depends on what you call a slice for what the answer is each time. but that's more a technicality. also there's a pattern I can see right now that may suggest the pattern for the whole thing.

Comment: To be clear: by slice you mean only a single stroke of the knife, not going through a previous cut?  So, for $n=3$ you have 6 pieces, right?

Comment: Yes, there is always 2n pieces above 0 slices. But the problem is that at 0, there is not 0 slices but 1. I am trying to find the formula for the number of exposed surface on an apple, so I decided to try a simpler version first, which I can't seem to solve.

Comment: Why is that a problem?  What is unsatisfying about $f(n)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if}~n=0\\2n&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$?

Comment: @JMoravitz's answer is honestly the neatest way of writing it. As you said, your formula does hold for any value of n above 0. So if you didn't feel like writing it as a piecewise function, you could always just say that the number of pieces is $2n$, for  $n > 0$

Comment: Thank you, I guess that is the only formula that would work. I wanted to make sure that there isn't a single line formula that would be able to describe all the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single line, I think people generally do this by an [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) or using the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta):
$$
\delta_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } i=j \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise }  \end{cases}
$$
Then, if you accept [$0^0=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1), you can write:
$$ f(n) = (2n)^{1-\delta_{0n}} $$
Or, more simply:
$$ f(n) = \delta_{0n} + 2n(1-\delta_{0n}) $$