Values of $0^0$
If $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $x^0=1$, or $0^x=0$, is there a possibility that $0^0$ can be any other value, e.g.: $0^0\stackrel{?}{=}2$, and if so, what other values can $0^0$ have?

Well, it can only be defined as one value, and we choose $0^0=1,$ when we choose to define it, because it is (1) the most useful definition, and (2) matches the combinatorial definition of exponentiation. But it is important to know that $x^y$ is discontinuous at $0,0$ so if $f(x)\to 0$ and $g(x)\to0$ we can't say what $f(x)^{g(x)}$ converges to - it can converge to anything or not,converge at all. This is often written as "$0^0$ is an indeterminate form." Indeterminate does not mean undefined.

In a computer program, I'd define $x^y=1$ when $y$ is an integer type variable, for any $x.$ But if $y$ was a floating point type, y=0.0 necesssarily might be an approximation, as,well,as $x=0.0,$ so we might leave that as undefined.

Please don't answer duplicate questions, and in any case don't answer questions in the comments. The value of $0^0$ has been discussed of course already on this site. Please use site search and mark it as a duplicate accordingly.

See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2462265/442
