# We know that $2^0$=1 but why $(-2)^0$=not 1

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, number-systems

"Any number to the power $0$ is $1$"- this is what I am taught. But my friend says that it is not true for negative numbers. Why? Well my friend said if you think $y=(-2)^0$ then $ln(y) = 0*ln(-2)$ then my friend said $ln(-2)$ is not valid. So we do not get a value. In case of $y= 2^0$ ; $lny= 0*ln2$, so $lny = 0$ then $y=1$. And one more question came into my mind that if $y= - 2$ then $lny= ln(-2)$ how is this possible?

Comment: It is true for *every* number, except for $0$ itself where there is no choice more natural than another.

Comment: @Magdiragdag I think you meant $(-2)^0=1$, instead of $0$.

Comment: Yes I really meant that @G. Sassatelli and Magdiragdag

Comment: Ask your friend why he thinks so... And he will finally conclude $(-2)^0=1$

Comment: Please give me the answer I have edited the question.

Comment: $\ln(a^b) = b \ln(a)$ only holds for $a > 0$, so the whole reasoning breaks down right at the start.

Comment: See my edited answer for the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero is an even number, and $(anything)^{even}>0$

$\ln({(-2)}^0) =\ln({|-2|}^0) = 0 \ln(|-2|)=0$

Comment: I never said why $(-2)^0=0 I said why this not 1

Comment: What I meant was there's no difference between $(-n)^{even}$ and $n^{even}$, so their values should be the same.

Comment: please see magdiragdag's comment in the bottom

Comment: Yes, I see. I am afraid a minor error he has made and that is: the negative number has an **even power**, so $a>0$ naturally and it satisfies the conditions for taking an $ln$ from it. Please refer to the first line of my answer. @Timerub

Comment: how can be 0<-2

Comment: We can't tell 0 odd or even as it can be divided by anything and not by itself

Comment: It is even because one way to prove that is you can rewrite it like $2k$ and not $2k+1$. You can refer to this article for full details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero
@Timerub

Comment: $(-2)^0 > 0$ so it is not $0<-2$ but $0<|-2|$ @Timerub

Comment: many many thanks for the answer to you

Comment: @Timerub glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $\forall a\neq0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by definition

$$a^0=a^{n-n}=\frac{a^n}{a^n}=1$$

see also the [related MSE OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 1):

$(B)^0 = (B)^{a-a}$ $= B^a / B^a= 1$

$(-B)^{a-a} = -B^a / -B^a  = 1 $

I don't know why your friend said that !!

Answer (score 1):

$$(-2)^3=(-2)\cdot (-2)\cdot (-2)=-8$$
$$(-2)^2=(-2)\cdot (-2)=4$$
$$(-2)^1=(-2)=-2$$
$$(-2)^0=?$$

In each step you divide by $-2$ to get to the next step. What do you think $(-2)^0$ should be?