# Can I assume that $0^0 = 0$ when dealing with the center of order $0$ in statistics?

Tags: analysis, limits, statistics

I came up to the concept of centers in statistics. Honestly, I never heard about this before few days ago.

> Given a collection of numbers $\{x_i\}$, $i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$, the
>   center of order $r$ is defined as the number $c$ which minimizes the
>   following function:
>
> $$f_r(c) = \sum_{i=1}^N \left|x_i - c\right|^r.$$

In particular, it comes out that:

1. The center of order $0$ is the mode of the collection $\{x_i\}$.
2. The center of order $1$ is the median of the collection $\{x_i\}$.
3. The center of order $2$ is the mean of the collection $\{x_i\}$.

---

For fun, I was able to prove point 3 (very easy) since $f$ is smooth. Point 2 is somehow hard, but I think I can solve it. Instead, for point 1, I'm having some troubles.

Consider the function $f_0(c)$. If $c \neq x_i$, then $x_i - c \neq 0$ and then
$$\left|x_i - c\right|^0 = 1.$$

Therefore, if I choose $c$ such that $c \neq x_i ~\forall i$, then I get that:

$$f_0(c) = N.$$

Now, $\color{red}{\text{I assume in this context that}~ 0^0 = 0}$.
That is, if $c = x_j$ for some $j$, I get:

$$\left|x_i - c\right|^0 = 0.$$

If the value of $x_j$ is repeated exactly $m$ times, then I get:

$$f_0(x_j) = N - m.$$

Therefore if $x_j$ correspond to the mode of the collection, then $m$ is maximum, and hence $f_0(x_j)$ attains its minimum.

Is this "proof" correct?

---

**A numerical "evidence"**

I consider the collection $\{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.
In this case, the mean is $3.125$, the median is $2.5$ (between $2$ and $3$) and the mode is $2$.

Hereafter, I plot the function $f_r(c)$ for $r=2$ (mean) and $r=1$ (median). Also I plot the function for $r=0.1$, $r=0.01$, $r=0.001$ and $r=0.0001$.

[image]

Comment: Defining $0^0=1$ is consistent with the formula for the mode. However defining $0^0$ to be any number less than $1$ is also consistent  with it... It is often assumed that  $0^0=1$, for example "Let $p(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n A_jx^j $ be a polynomial" where the term $A_0x^0$  is assumed to be $A_0$ even when $ x=0 .$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet If I assume $0^0=1$, then $f_0(c) = N$ for all $c$.

Comment: Sorry.You are right about that. I was sleepy.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet no problem, and thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is nice, but I think the mode needs to be more carefully defined.

Of course, $0^0$ is undefined. Moreover, if you are taking the limit of $x^0$ as $x \rightarrow 0,$ that limit is 1. Consequently, in many software packages `0^0` returns $1,$ on the assumption that the base $0$ is likely to be an 'underflow' (roughly, a number too small to handle within the the range of rational values the computer can represent), and not a 'genuine' $0.$

In R statistical software for example:

```
0^0
## 1

n = 1:6;  x = 1/(n^(n^n));  b=x^0  
cbind(n, x, b)   # 6 x 3 matrix
     n             x b
[1,] 1  1.000000e+00 1
[2,] 2  6.250000e-02 1
[3,] 3  1.311373e-13 1
[4,] 4 7.458341e-155 1
[5,] 5  0.000000e+00 1  # x is underflow
[6,] 6  0.000000e+00 1  # x is underflow
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work out so well in the (presumably rarer) case, in which it's the *exponent* that tends to $0.$
Thus programmers do have to be careful some of the time.

```
n = 1:6;  x = 1/(n^(n^n));  c=0^x  
cbind(n, x, c)
     n             x c
[1,] 1  1.000000e+00 0
[2,] 2  6.250000e-02 0
[3,] 3  1.311373e-13 0
[4,] 4 7.458341e-155 0
[5,] 5  0.000000e+00 1
[6,] 6  0.000000e+00 1
```

Comment: "Of course, $0^0$ is undefined." — There's no "of course" here. As soon as you define it, it is not undefined. *In the context of limits,* there's no useful definition of $0^0$. In *most other contexts*, the most useful definition is $0^0=1$. The question is whether in *this* context, one should define $0^0=0$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1223154/34930) I explained the question of $0^0$ in detail. $0^0=0$ is one of the sensible definitions I describe there, but I didn't see where it could be useful. It might be that this is a context where it is indeed the most useful definition.

Comment: @celtschk for some $n > 0$, we have that $0^0 = 0^{n-n} = \frac{0^n}{0^n} = \frac 00$. If $n = 0$ then we obtain that $0^0 = \frac{0^0}{0^0}$ and therefore $$\begin{align} \frac 00 &= \frac{0^0}{0^0} \\ \\ \Leftrightarrow 0 &= 0^0.\end{align}$$ However, this may not be entirely true. $$\frac 33 = \frac 55 = 1,$$ but $3 \neq 5$. So how can we define $0^0$ to be equal to $0$? It seems like it is only sensible to define $0^0$ as being equal to $1$ because $$\lim_{k\to 0}k^k = 1.$$

Comment: @user477343: How can we define $0^0$ to equal $0$? Simple: Just do it. You cannot **derive** $0^0=0$, but you can *define* it, and you'll find that by doing this, that all power laws continue to hold. Note that you cannot use division by zero in your argumentation, unless you define *that* first. Now if you define $0^{-1}=0$, too, you no longer have $aa^{-1}=1$. But there does exist an algebraic structure where $a^{-1}$ is always defined, but in general $aa^{-1}\ne bb^{-1}$: completely regular semigroups. Indeed, with $0^0=0^{-1}=0$, $(\mathbb R,\cdot)$ is a completely regular semigroup.

Comment: @celtschk thank you for explaining that to me :)

Comment: To add, we sometimes (erroneously) say that $0^0$ is undefined, but what we really mean is that there's no way to define it so that, for any $f$ and $g$ such that $f(a) = g(a) = 0$ and both $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $x=a$, $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is also continuous at $a$. The word which describes this phenomenon is "indeterminate" and applies to other examples such as $0/0$ (and some expressions involving infinity with a careful definition of "continuous at infinity").

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway, I don't understand how this can help to solve to my question. I'm aware about all the theory around $0^0$. What about the proof on the mode?

Comment: In your computational addendum with the nice graphs, I see you have used $r = 2,\, r= 1,$ and $r \rightarrow 0.$ The purpose of my 'Answer' was  announced in the first sentence: the mode needs to be more carefully defined. My extended examples in R show not $0^0$ but two relevant limiting relationships. You have discovered the useful one of the two. Now I suggest you clean up the mess by defining the relevant property of the mode in a mathematically rigorous way using a limit. You are almost there. (But the 'explanation' you liked best does not lead toward a rigorous treatment.)

Comment: @BruceET thanks, I will try to work on this a little bit. Anyway, I did not vote any answer yet.

Comment: Less concerned about votes than putting ideas together for an intuitive, yet rigorous version of this idea of 'explaining' mean, median, and mode. Your graphs seem a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree

$$f(x)=0^0 = a^x$$

using maclaurin series

$$a^x = 1 + x\ln a + \frac{x^2}{2!} (\ln a)^2 +. . . + \frac{x^n}{n!} (\ln a)^n$$

thus when $a = 0 , x= 0$

$$0^0 = 1 - \frac{0}{0} +\frac{0}{0} +. . . +(-1)^n+\frac{1}{0} \quad \text{because in} \quad 0 = -\frac{1}{0} \quad \text{i.e} \quad -\infty$$

hence $0^0 = 1 - \frac{0}{0} = \frac{0}{0}$

. : we can't assume that $0^0 = 0$

even the limit as $k \to 0$ , if the function is $k^k$ is not absolutely true

Comment: Please go here $\longrightarrow$ https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: There's no MacLaurin series in the context of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway, I don't understand how this can help to solve to my question. I'm aware about all the theory around $0^0$. What about the proof on the mode?