# Optimizing the limit of a sequence of nondifferentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, optimization

> Consider $N \in \mathbb{N}$ real numbers $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \ldots
>  \leq  a_N.$ Moreover, consider the following sequence of functions:
>
> $$f_{k}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N |x-a_i|^\frac{1}{k},$$
>
> where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Let
>
> $$f(x) = \lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(x).$$
>
> I would like to know which are the tools that I can use to find the
>   value of $x \in [a_1, a_N]$ such that $f(x)$ attains its minimum (or
>   its infimum).

The intuition led me the following road.

1. Suppose that all the members of the set $A = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots a_N\}$ are distinct. If $x \not\in A$, then:

$$f(x) = \lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^N|x-a_i|^\frac{1}{k} =\\= \sum_{i=1}^N\lim_{k \to \infty}|x-a_i|^\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{i=1}^N (\text{some positive number})^0 = N.$$

Instead, if $x \in A$ (let say WLOG $x = a_N$) then:

$$f(x) = \lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^N|x-a_i|^\frac{1}{k} =\\= \sum_{i=1}^N\lim_{k \to \infty}|x-a_i|^\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} (\text{some positive number})^0  + 0^0 = N-1 + 0^0.$$

Numerically, I observe that "$0^0$" seems to be very close to $0$. **This is the most controversial part of my efforts. How can I evaluate this indeterminate form resulting in a $0^0$?**. 
Therefore, the minimum is attained for any $x \in A$.

2. Suppose that all members of $A$ are distinct except for $a_r = a_{r+1} = \ldots = a_N.$ Therefore, if $x \not \in A$, we still get $N$. Anyway, if $x = a_r$, then:

$$f(x) = \lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^N|x-a_i|^\frac{1}{k} =\\= \sum_{i=1}^N\lim_{k \to \infty}|x-a_i|^\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{i=1}^{r-1} (\text{some positive number})^0  + (N-r+1)0^0 \\=\\ r-1 + (N-r+1)0^0.$$

Again, numerical experiments suggest my that in this case $0^0$ is close to $0$. Therefore the minimum is attained for $x = a_r$.

Do you have some hints for a more precise and rigorous approach? Thanks!

---

This question has been asked after [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2653473/can-i-assume-that-00-0-when-dealing-with-the-center-of-order-0-in-statist).

Comment: $\lim_{k\to\infty}0^{1/k}=0$. So there is no problem with $0^0$.

Comment: @d.k.o. thanks a lot. What if I would have had $$f(x) = \lim_{r \to 0}\sum_{i=1}^N|x-a_i|^r?$$

Comment: $r\to 0$ is the same as $k\to \infty$.

Comment: @d.k.o. stupid question after a hard day. Thanks again.