# A little confused about the Taylor series of $e^x$

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function

We know that

$$
e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!},x\in \mathbb R,
$$

which can be written out
$$
e^x=\frac {x^0}{0!}+\frac {x^1}{1!}+\frac {x^2}{2!}+\cdots,
$$

but $0^0$ isn't well defined.

Comment: So is your question about the series at zero?

Comment: In this case we take $0^0=1.$

Comment: One usually defines $0^0$ as an exact quantity to be $1$ whether in the setting of analysis or the discrete situation. But it is important to keep in mind that $f(x,y)=x^y$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ with this definition (or any other definition) of $0^0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general formulation of Taylor series centered at $x=0$,
$$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2 + \ldots$$
(where the equality above holds on analytic functions -- don't worry about these technicalities at this time). Thus, for $f(x) = e^x$, we get
$$e^x = e^0 + e^0 x + \frac{e^0}{2!} x^2 + \ldots = 1 + x + \frac{1}{2!} x^2 + \ldots$$
You'll notice that your $0^0$ doesn't appear here; that's because this formula is *really* what the Taylor series of $e^x$ whereas you are right in saying that the collapsed formula in summation notation is technically undefined at $x=0$. Just think of summation notation as a shorthand (or "notational trick") for this formula, where this formula *is* valid for all $x$. Often times in math, mathematicians do away with details in their notation that makes it "technically incorrect", for the purpose of communicating something at a high/concise level.