# Is $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^x}$ continuous at $x=0$?

Tags: limits, continuity

I was discussing with this person online because they (basically) claimed that $$f(x)=\frac{x}{x^x}$$ is equal to 0 at $x=0$.

I argued this was not technically true because in order to get to that result you would have to "simplify" the function the following way:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac{x}{x^x}\\
&=\frac{1}{x^{x-1}}\\
\end{align}
$$

And so, when evaluating at $x=0$ we get $f(0)=0$.

We both agree to this point, but I'm arguing that that's taking the limit as $x\rightarrow 0^+$. He, on the other hand, argues that this is, in fact, not taking the limit but the value of the function itself.

We are now curious and don't really want a short answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question?  The title question is not what you speak of in your post.

Comment: My initial answer contained a mistake that I have corrected now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to discuss continuity and discontinuity of a function $f$, it has to be defined there. If $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{x^x}$, then $f(0)=\dfrac{0}{0^0}$. Whether or not this expression has any meaning depends on whether you leave $0^0$ undefined, or define it as $1$:

- If you leave $0^0$ undefined, then $f$ is undefined at $0$, and so it whether it is continuous at $0$ is also undefined. To understand why, consider that the usual definition of continuity of $f$ at $a$ is
  $$
  \DeclareMathOperator{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}
  \DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}
  \forall\epsilon>0:\exists\delta>0:\forall x\in\dom(f):|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon \, .
  $$
  For this definition to make any sense, we need $f(a)$ to be defined. However, we can define a new function $\hat{f}$ that is continuous at $0$:
  $$
  \hat{f}(x)=
  \begin{cases}
  \dfrac{x}{x^x} &\text{if $x>0 \, $,} \\[4pt]
  0 &\text{if $x=0 \, $.}
  \end{cases}
  $$
- If you define $0^0$ as $1$, then $f(0)=0$, and you can discuss continuity of $f$ at $0$. Since
  $$
  \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x}{x^x}=\frac{\lim_{x \to 0^+}x}{\lim_{x \to 0^+}x^x}=\frac{0}{1}=0 \, ,
  $$
  $f$ is continuous at $0$.

In any case, the simplification $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{x^x}=\dfrac{1}{x^{x-1}}$ is only valid when $x>0$, as $0^{-1}$ is *always* left undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The formula $f(x) = x/x^x$ is undefined at $x=0,$ since if you plug in $f(0) = 0/0^0$  you get nonsense. However, you can define $f(0)$ to be whatever you'd like. A function is not a formula, it is merely a collection of input output pairs.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. Why should $\frac{0}{0^0}$ be nonsense? $0^0$ is very often defined as $1$, and with good reason.

Comment: @Joe: But very seldom is this done in Calculus, as it runs the risk of introducing multiple exceptions to limit laws.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It is done all the time in calculus with series. Like how the series expansion for $e^x$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}x^n$, even at $x=0$ where that has a $0^0$ in it.

Comment: @alex.jordan: I teach calculus all the time; that's not my experience. This is, at best, an arguable position, but hardly a settled fact as Joe (and you?) seem to take it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I'm not saying that $0^0$ is *always* defined as $1$ in *all* contexts. But calling it nonsense is a step too far.

Comment: Sorry, I was just disputing the "very seldom done in calculus" part. Do you write Taylor series like $1+\sum_{n=1}c_nx^n$ to avoid having $0^0$ arise? That would be reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

The function's formula is $\frac{x}{x^x}$, and if you want to investigate its propoerties at $x=0$, you should work with that originally given formula for the function. Simplification to another formula is often only valid on a subset of the domain.

So $f(0)=\frac{0}{0^0}$. You have to confront what you want $0^0$ to mean. There are several valid positions to take regarding the value of $0^0$. See [a post on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1) about it.

One position is that $0^0$ is an empty product, and therefore equal to $1$, regardless of the base of that expression being $0$. In that case $f(0)=\frac{0}{1}=0$. If this is the position your friend takes, it is correct to conclude $0$ is the actual value of $f(0)$.

But of course $0^0$ might mean something else to someone else. And depending on what it means to them, then $f(0)$ is probably undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If we write your functions as such:
$$f(x) = x\,e^{-x\log x},$$
then we see that the value of your function at $x=0$ is undefined because $\log 0$ does not exist. *However*, if we take the limit as $x\to 0^+$ of our function, we find that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0$. You can now *define* $f(0)=0$, and your function will be right-continuous at $x=0$. Is it not continuous there because the left limit does not exist since your function isn't defined for negative $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$$
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{x^x}=x^{1-x}=e^{(1-x)\ln(x)}$$
$$g(x)=\ln f(x)=(1-x)\ln(x)$$
$$\ln(L)=\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=-\infty$$
so:
$$L=\lim_{y\to-\infty}\exp(y)=0$$
however, this is the limit from above

Comment: You have written that $L = \lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$. How do you know that the limit exists?

Answer (score 0):

Re-write as $\frac{x}{\exp(x\log(x))}$.

The function $\exp$ is everywhere continuous. By L’Hopital’s rule, $x\log(x)$ tends to 0. Therefore the denominator of the original fraction tends to 1. Since the numerator tends to 0, the fraction tends to 0.

Setting the value of f(0) to 0 makes f continuous for x positive (well, left continuous at 0).