# Confused about a step in a proof of convergence of a power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Consider the power series $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(x-a)^n$.It is required to prove that it converges at $x=a$. Here is a [link](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/PowerSeries.aspx) that attempts at this. 
My issue is the appearance of $0^0$ and then the conclusion that it equals $1$. I always thought it was undefined. 
What now? There might be other proofs of convergence of this power series, but isn't this result obtained,well,undefined? Does this proof need some fixing?
Hints are fine. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11150/8581) may be helpful!

Comment: Ah this is rather a matter of convention. Usually, of course, this is undefined at $x = a$. But You can just define that $0^0= 1$ in that case such that everything works out for every value. Similar thing is done in measure theory where one defines $\infty \cdot 0 = 0$.  In general this of course makes no sense but in some NARROW SCENARIOS this type of convention is acceptable.

Comment: It will be a duplicate, but $0^0$ is generally taken to be $1$, especially in power series such as $e^x=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and binomial expansions $(a+b)^n =\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}a^kb^{n-k}$ and combinatorial uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} c_n (x-a)^n$$

is a notation that gathers the sum $c_0 + c_1 (x-a) + c_2 (x-a)^2 + ...$ to avoid the iterative writing of terms and the "...". So:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} c_n (x-a)^n = c_0 + c_1 (x-a) + c_2 (x-a)^2 + ...$$

So, there's no $0^0$ indetermination in power series, it's just a matter of notation to make a compact sum. A power series always converges at its center $x=a$.