# Indeterminate power direct substitution

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

Suppose that we have $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)}$ with $f(a)=0$ and $g(a)=0$.

Can we say, that the value of the above limit is $0^0=1$?

Is there a counterexample?

UPDATE: I already saw examples you've provided. Is there a counterexample with continuous functions?

Comment: You should rule out $f(x)\equiv 0$ as a trivial counterexample.

Comment: May I ask you to make it a bit clear? Thanks

Comment: This is an indeterminate form, so it can do just about anything.

Comment: Is there no hypothesis about $f$ and $g$? Then consider $f $ defined by $f(x) = 2$ for $x\ne a$ and $f(a)=0$, and $g=f$. Then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)} = 2^2 = 4$.

Comment: Even if we have $f(x)=g(x)=x$ and $a=0$ , the conditions are satisfied, but the limit does not even exist (only the limit from the right exists)

Answer (score 0):

Counter-example: $\lim_{x\to 0} $[1-cosx$]^x$ ,where [ ] stands for greatest integer function.

Edit:
Another example I found in the below linked answer :
$\lim_{x\to 0+}x^\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$

A similar discussion which took place here: [Zero to the zero power – is $0^0=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1)