# What's wrong with this proof of $0! = 1$

Tags: taylor-expansion, factorial, fake-proofs

I was trying to find $0!$  using the series expansion of $e^x$ and got some odd results.

---

We know that,
$$e^x = \sum_{n =0}^\infty\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$

Putting $x = 0$ will give us following results.

$$e^0 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{0^n}{n!}\implies1 = \dfrac{0^0}{0!} +\underbrace{ \dfrac{0^1}{1!} + \dfrac{0^2}{2!} + ...\infty}_0$$

So, we are ended up with $1 = \dfrac{0^0}{0!}$

On cross multiplication, we have $0! = 0^0$ (I'm not sure if cross multiplication is a valid step here).

What to do with this? Can we conclude that $0^0 = 1$ because $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+} x^x = 1?$

Is the step of cross multiplication really a valid step above?

Comment: The definition of $0!$ is $1$, so is the definition of $0^0$, however some authors prefer to keep the latter undefined. I personally disagree with that convention though.

Comment: @SiriusBlack I corrected a few typos.

Comment: Do you want to conclude that $0!=1$, or that $0^0=1$? For the second question, series and polynomials are written under the assumption that $x^0$ stands for the constant $1$ function, so if you manipulate power series you shoud just re-discover it. I can see a few reasons for that choice, but I have never heard of $x^x\to 1$ as $x\to 0^+$ playing a role: in fact, $x\ln x\to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$ is not a particularly comfortable statement to handle with power series. There are reasonable combinatorial arguments in terms of functions $\varnothing \to\varnothing$ for the choice $0!=0^0=1$.

Comment: We should really note that the series expansion of $e^x$ only features a "$0!$" factorial because to begin with we know the constant coefficient is $1$, and it is just more elegant to express $1$ as $0!$ to fit it into the series. So, this argument could never work anyway

Comment: The hitch is that your "proof" use a convention : $0^0=1$ which cannot be taken for granted. So this method would lead to no more than another convention. Discussion about $0^0$ : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14709220/Zero-puissance-zero-Zero-to-the-Zero-th-Power

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zero to the zero power – is $0^0=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1)

Comment: I think the formula assumes that $0!=1$ so as to make the writing of it neat. But I could be wrong. So if I am wrong, recall that the derivative of the exponential is the same function. Then the second term of the derivative of the sum, that is, the term at index $1$, must give $0!=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say: facts $(1)$ and $(2)$ are are used in the proof of fact $(3)$.  Therefore, it would be "circlular" to deduce $(1)$ or $(2)$ from $(3)$.

$$
x^0 = 1\quad\text{where $x$ is a real variable}
\tag1$$

$$
0! = 1
\tag2$$

$$
e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}
\tag3$$

---

I stated $(1)$ in this peculiar way because that formulation is more widely accepted than
$$
0^0=1
\tag{1'}$$