# How to understand why $x^0 = 1$, where $x$ is any real number?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, exponential-function

Alright, so the idea of an exponent, $x$, is that you are multiplying its base by itself $x$ number of times. With base $5$ and $x=3$, we have that $5^3$ = $5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5$

I understand that the logarithm with base $a$ of $x = c$,

tells us that

$$a^c = x$$

and for $c =$ positive; values for $x$ are greater than $1$, 
and for $c =$ negative; values for $x$ are less than $1$,  
and for $c = 0$, values for $x$ are...$1$.

So in short, I understand how, by means of observation of the graph of $f(x) = \log x$, we can see that $f(1) = 0$, BUT, I see no other way to understand why $x^0 = 1$, apart from the graph and everything *around* that very point.

I honestly cannot get my head around the idea, "$5$ times itself $0$ times... is one".

Is it that there is no fundamental answer for this but that we simply know by the graph? Or can I truly understand $x^0 = 1$ on its own?

Comment: It's a *definition*, based mainly, perhaps, on some facts related to limits. It also makes a lot of sense within the context of series, in particular geometric ones. By the way, to avoid problems we usually require $\,x\neq 0\,$, otherwise things get a little foggy...

Comment: The previous question on [numbers to the power of zero](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/235081/856) seems to be a proper superset of this one.

Comment: so it seems, but I'm glad for these answers all the same

Comment: The possibility of $x=0$ needs to be treated as a special case.

Comment: In all honestly, "5 times itself 0 times... is one" is not indisputably true, "5 to the power of 0 is one" is true on the other hand. The exponential function is conveniently defined as "a number times itself" for integer operands. Note: "5 times itself 0 times", how do you write that with the multiplication operand? You don't, and that's the problem :)

Comment: @BenCrowell: No, $x=0$ does _not_ need special consideration. An empty product is an empty product, it cannot depend on what would have been in the product if it had not been empty. Anyone haveing qualms about indefinite forms should start to realize that $x^y$ for **positive real** $x$ just means $\exp(y\ln x)$, and the qualms will go away without having to undefine $0^0$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/0to0.html

Comment: @FlybyNight: That is about the worst argument for not defining $0^0$ that I've seen. "The problem is similar to that with division by zero". No it isn't at all, there are plenty equations that perfectly well fix the value $0^0=1$ (like $X^0=1$ for the polynomial $X$; now substitute $X=0$); just the equation $0^1=0\times0^0$ does not fix it, so what? Also "$0$ to any positive power is $0$, so $0$ to the power $0$ should be $0$". Huh? Swallowing $n$ doses of cyanide is lethal for $n>0$, so it should be lethal for $n=0$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen You seem to have quite an axe to grind. I guess these guys are wrong too: (6m40s) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRRolKTlF6Q

Comment: @FlybyNight: You guessed right; this is indeed even more stupid than the other reference. They actually say that $\lim_{x\to0^-}x^x=1$ (which argument they then sweep away), but in fact any negative real number taken to a negative non-integral power isn't (well) defined at all, so that limit simply cannot be taken. And complex numbers to non-integral complex powers aren't well defined either.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I guess we're all wrong, and you're right.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen True, every empty product is the same. But you are using a convention that $0^0$ literally means an empty product, and further, that the empty product should equal $1$. Who made _those_ decisions? We all agree on a meaning for $x^n$ with $n\in Z$. We all agree on $x^n$ with $n\in Q$ and $x\in R^{+}$ using radicals. But unless you take my answer's approach (quite different than the first answer you'll get from any math teacher) then neither of these apply or extend to $0^0$. Your fervent belief about $0^0$ is rooted in your own convention, and not everyone uses that.

Comment: I probably should just stay out of this thread :) But regardless of whether $0^0=1$, @BenCrowell's point is valid. $0^0$ does need special consideration since the more common "backwards induction" argument does not apply. You see what I mean? Fine - it should equal $1$ under common conventions, but a decent explanation for why $2^0=1$ won't always be a good explanation for why $0^0=1$.

Comment: @alex.jordan: I don't want to prolong the discussion here, maybe I'll post an explicit question some day. But I'm amazed by this comment from you. By _your own anwer_ we should think of $x^n$ (with $n\geq0$) as $1\times x\times\cdots\times x$ with $n$ occurrences of "${}\times x$". Now take $n=0$ and $x=0$ and you get $0^0=1$, no sweat. And this **is** an instance of $x^n$ with $n\in\mathbf Z$ that "we all agree on" (your words).

Comment: $MarcvanLeeuwen My earlier comment's wording was less than ideal because of character limits. [This site](http://www.askamathematician.com/2010/12/q-what-does-00-zero-raised-to-the-zeroth-power-equal-why-do-mathematicians-and-high-school-teachers-disagree/) expresses my stance, that we make a choice for convenience and rationalize it later. My answer is that _a posteriori_ argument for OP's sake. I think that you and I would both leave OP taking $x^0$ to be 1 for _all_ $x$, but I would point out how most arguments fail for $x=0$, and show how reasonable minds and books will still disagree.

Comment: The idea that **exponentiation can be represented as iterated (repeated) multiplication** really only holds for **natural number exponents**. Think about negative exponents: what is 5 times itself, negative 2 times? It doesn't make sense in our minds, even though we know the value of $5^{-2}$. Even worse is with rational, and worse, irrational, exponents. Mathematically we have a way of calculating them, but we don't tend to think of them as iterated multiplication. This concept breaks down when we get to 0-valued exponents as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is $x^0 = 1$ except when $x = 0$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135/why-is-x0-1-except-when-x-0)

Comment: @khaverim:  Do not be fooled by the answers below (like the one by Golob).  If they do not mention domain theory (and just use clever manipulations of symbols), they are not correct.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

$x^{n+1}=x\cdot x^n$ right?

so

$x^1=x \cdot x^0$ but $x=x^1$ so for that to hold true, $x^0$ must be $1$.

Similarily,

$\large x^{-n} = \frac{1}{x^n}$.

So $\large x^n \cdot x^{-n} = x^n \frac{1}{x^n} = 1$.

But $\large x^n \cdot x^{-n} = x^{n+(-n)} = x^0$, so once more, $x^0=1$.

There are really many reasons for that to hold, and all of them are just a consequence of some agreements we've made previously.

Comment: Alright, appreciated.

Comment: You need to assume that $x \neq 0.$ The expression $0^0$ is not well defined. http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/0to0.html

Comment: It is implicitly assumed when I devide sides by $x=x^1$ since one cannot devide by 0.

Answer (score 39):

Don't think of $x^n$ as $\overbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}^{n\text{ copies}}$. Instead think of $x^n$ as representing the result of starting with $1$ and applying "${}\cdot x$" $n$ times: $1\overbrace{{}\cdot x\cdot x\cdot{}\cdots{}\cdot x}^{n\text{ copies}}$.

This also makes negative exponents a little nicer for beginners. $x^{-n}$ is just applying the opposite of ${}\cdot x$, which is ${}\div x$, $n$ times. $x^{-n}=1\overbrace{{}\div x\div x\div\cdots\,\div x}^{n\text{ copies}}$.

Comment: This is better than "backward induction" from the cases $n=\ldots,2,1$, and it works painlessly if $x=0$.

Answer (score 10):

There are many answers about why $x^0 = 1$ for general $x$, so I'd like to address a different issue here, the way you think about exponentiation, which seems to be troubling you.

The definition you use for exponentiation holds true for integers, and rationals if you define what $x^{1/n}$ means, but what about the irrationals? How can you times something by itself $\sqrt{2}$ times? The answer is - you can't! You need to come up with some sensible way to define exponentiation rigorously.

We define $$e^x = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
which is  absolutely convergent for any complex $x$, and only depends on us defining what $x^n$ means for the natural numbers and $0$. Considering the function restricted to the reals we can use this definition to show that the function is continuous, differentiable, has an inverse $\ln{x}$ and satisfies all the properties that we are used to with exponentiation. To then define, $a^x$ for $a \not= e$ we say $a^x = e^{x\ln(a)}$. This obeys all the properties that we want it to for rational $x$ and has the added bonus of being well defined on the irrationals too.

In fact, the definition of $e^x$ can even be seen as a motivation to define $x^0$ as $1$. $x^n$ for any natural $n$ is defined intuitively, but choosing any value for $x^0$ which is not $1$ will mean that this definition of $e^x$ will not longer obey the rules we have come to know and love e.g. $e^{a+b} = e^{a}e^{b}$. When you look at it like this, you really have no choice!

I hope you find this useful!

Comment: A great perspective, although I'm slow to digest it all. We just reviewed that definition of $e^x$ in Calc II

Comment: No problem, showing all the consequences of the definition that I stated would take a lecture or two and then some thought afterwards. I just wanted to convey the idea of how to think of exponentiation in a more formal, rigorous way, and the idea that our exponential function only works if $x^0 = 1$ just sort of fell out whilst doing it - so that was a nice surprise!

Comment: To prevent bumping the post, I refrain from an edit, but there is an error here:
$$a^x = e^{x\ln a}$$
and not the other way around.

Answer (score 8):

These are all good answers. [Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) another way to think about it via the empty product. It may be the best way to see it "on its own". It also provides a nice way of thinking about other seemingly paradoxical operations involving zero like $0^0$ and $0!$

The empty product basically says that the product of no factors is 1. It is necessary if we want to recursively define a product of a set of commutative elements.

Comment: Ah, great stuff. thanks!

Comment: That is a good way to state it, but it's still better to understand the domain theory behind it.

Answer (score 7):

Well $5^{x} = 5^{0 + x} = 5^{0} 5^{x}$. Dividing by $5^{x}$ yields $1 = 5^{0}$. If you define at all, I don't think you will have a better choice.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep "the idea of an exponent, $x$, is that you are multiplying its base by itself $x$ number of times" then a simple way to think about is as follows:

$x^0 = 1 \times x^0 = 1x^0 = 1 \overbrace{\phantom{\small{x\text{ multiplied by itself 0 times}}}}^{x\text{ multiplied by itself 0 times}} = 1$

This works because $1$ is identity of multiplication ($\times$).

Comment: You, sir, get credit for the most hilarious proof of $x^0=1$.

Answer (score 5):

$\dfrac{a^b}{a^c} = a^{b-c}$ for $a \gt 0$.  Now let $b=c$.

It can get more complicated for $a \lt 0$ and $b$ and $c$ non-integers, while for $a=0$ it is just a convenient definition.

Answer (score 5):

I see that this question already has *seventeen* answers, but I'm going to jump on the bandwagon because as a set theorist I feel very underrepresented by the current answers.

For $m,n \in \mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,\dots\}$ we can define $m^n$ to be the number of functions from a set of size $n$ to a set of size $m$. For instance,
$$3^5 = \text{the number of functions}\ \{1,2,3,4,5\} \to \{1,2,3\}$$
There's only one set of size $0$, namely the empty set $\varnothing$, and so for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$
$$m^0 = \text{the number of functions}\ \varnothing \to \{1,2,\dots,m\}$$
But for any value of $m$ there is only one such function, namely the [empty function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_function). (This *is* a function: its domain is empty so it satisfies the definition trivially.) Therefore $m^0 = 1$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

This definition of exponentiation extends naturally to $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}, \cdots$ and also to infinite [cardinal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_exponentiation).

More interestingly, according to this definition, we have $0^0=1$ (since there is exactly one function $\varnothing \to \varnothing$) without any fear of lack of definition. (It *does* mean that the function $x \mapsto 0^x$ is discontinuous at $0$, but who cares? It means that the power series definition of $\exp x$ is well-defined at $0$, which I think trumps this caveat!)

Answer (score 3):

What is $5$ added to itself $0$ times? The answer is $0$. Why? $0$ is the nothing of addition. It works the same way with $1$. You can change $5^0$ to $(5^0)\times1$. That is the thought behind it. Another way to look at it is a a nice and sleek definition I like for exponents. $x^1=x$ and $x^m\times x^n$=$x^{m+n}$. That means $x^n\times x^0=x^{n+0}=x^n$. This goes back to the idea of $1$ being the identity of multiplication.

Comment: I think it'd be a good idea, before you even answer questions, that you first learn how to properly type mathematics in this site with LaTeX. In the FAQ are some directions and it's pretty easy.

Comment: I changed your formatting with LaTeX to make it a bit more readable, you may want to look over what I did to see how to make things show up more clearly in the future. Also, I think the idea of $1$ being the "nothing" of multiplication is misleading, since the nothing of multiplication could just as well mean zero. I think a better word is "identity" since that means that it "acts trivially" or "acts by not changing what it acts on" in a more general sense.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can "truly understand it on its own".

"5 times itself 0 times..." is just too naïve a way to think about it.  It's true that we initially define powers by iterated multiplication, and in this context it is obvious that $x^{n+m} = x^n\times x^m$.  Given this, there is an obvious generalisation for rational exponents: define $x^{\frac{p}{q}}$ to be the $q^{\mathrm{th}}$ root of $x^p$.  The final step is also obvious: demand that $x^y$ be continuous in $y$.

I don't know a 'more fundamental' way to understand this.

Comment: Although, I would interpret "5 times itself 0 times" as the empty product, which is defined to be 1.

Comment: @ZachLangley: I'm not sure that helps.  You've used the words 'interpret' and 'defined'...

Comment: Your answer was quite helpful

Comment: @Rhys It doesn't help.  I was just suggesting that there is nothing wrong with thinking about $5^0$ as $5$ times itself $0$ times.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $1$ is the same as not multiplying by anything at all, so it's the same as multiplying by $5$ zero times.

Answer (score 1):

**RULE 1**

$$\frac{x^m}{x^n} = x^{m-n}$$

thus if m=3 and n=3,

$$\frac{x^3}{x^3} = x^{3-3} = x^0$$

**RULE 2**

Anything devided by its self is 1, why?

$$\frac{10}{10} = 1,$$

because $\frac{y}{y} = y\left(\frac{1}{y}\right) = \left(\frac{y}{1}\right)\times \left(\frac{1}{y}\right)$ which can be displayed as

$$ \frac{y}{1} \times \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$$

here the $y$ values cancel out to become 1

**COMBINING THE RULES**

so if anything devided by it's self is 1 
and $x^0 = x^{m-n} = \frac{x^m}{x^n}$
then
$X^0$ **must = 1**, as its simply just a way of saying that value devided by itself =?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking $x^0$ is *defined* to be 1 so that the power rules work out nicely for positive and negative powers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that $r^0=1$ mostly to make exponent arithmetics consistent.
Since $r^a\cdot r^b=r^{a+b}$ and since $r^a=\frac{1}{r^{-a}}$ we get:
\begin{align}
r^0 = r^{a-a}= r^a\cdot r^{-a}=r^a\cdot\frac 1 {r^a}=\frac{r^a}{r^a}=1
\end{align}
So any other than $1$ defenition to $r^0$ would be inconsistent with exponent arithmetics.

Answer (score 0):

There are good answers on this question but a visual representation of `pow` function may be useful too.

Please, consider this patterns

```
    ...
x^3  = x*x*x
x^2  = x*x
x^1  = x
x^0  = ?????
x^-1 = ?????
    ...

    ...
x^3  = 1*x*x*x
x^2  = 1*x*x
x^1  = 1*x
x^0  = 1
x^-1 = 1/x
x^-2 = 1/x/x
x^-3 = 1/x/x/x
    ...
```

A simple traditional definition of `pow` function means **how many times we multiply a number by self**.

But in more strict sense `pow` function means **how many times we multiply or divide the one by a number**.

By this reason `x^0 = 1` => `0^0 = (-1)^0 = 1` too.

[image: x^0 = 1]

In [a more general case](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) the `seed` may be any number.

```
static double Pow(double x, int pow, double seed = 1d)
{
    var value = seed;
    
    if (pow < 0)
        for (var i = 0; i > pow; i--) value /= x;
    else
        for (var i = 0; i < pow; i++) value *= x;
    
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

$x^{n-1}=\frac{x^n}{x}$

$x^0=x^{1-1}=\frac{x^1}{x}=\frac{x}{x}=1$

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your identity doesn't hold true for $x = 0$. In another words, $x \in \mathbb R^+$. For the intuition,$$ a^0 = a^{x  -x } = { {a^x} \over {a^x}} = 1$$

---

Another:
$$a^{n -1} = {a^n \over a}$$Now,$$a^{1 - 1} = {a^1 \over a} = {a^1 \over a^1} = 1$$

Comment: Here you have an assumption that a is not equal to zero so please mention that.

Answer (score -2):

So many have given so many answers

But on my behalf i want to put it in simple terms as below

Apply $\log$ on both sides so it becomes
$$ \log x^0 = \log 1 $$
here $\log 1$ is zero
and the rule of logarithms says that $\log a^b = b\cdot \log a$

so it would be $0\log x = 0$
So they are equal.

Simple right :)

Comment: Are you assuming $x^0 = 1$?  You should reverse your argument.

Comment: yes i assumed that and at last i have proved it as well

Answer (score -4):

First of all you(not only you many) have to understand mathematics is also a language, another way of communication. Language is obviously based on grammar( lexical rules). Power is a operation which is based on multiplication. $2^2$ means its just a language which convey you that you have to multiply 2 number 2 times. $2^0$ means you should not use 2 at all. Automatically our mind fills the number 1 instead of void.

Comment: Why should our mind fill in with 1 rather than any other number?? Mystical sounding hokum is not mathematics!

Comment: Why would our minds choose to fill the void with $1$? Why not $0$? Why not $\infty$? There has to be a better explanation than this.