# Why is $\ln 1 = 0 $?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, intuition

Yes I know, and believe, and have used it for all the time I have done mathematics as fun as well as a subject. But why is it that $$\ln 1 = 0$$

Comment: How have you seen $ln$ defined?

Comment: $\ln(ab) = \ln(a)+\ln(b)$

Comment: $e^x=1 \implies x=?$

Comment: Presumably because $\text{NapLog}(1) \approx 161180956.51$ (perhaps actually closer to $161180948.4$) turned out  to be rather inconvenient.

Comment: If you consider the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Problems_with_inverting_the_complex_exponential_function) then, since $\,e^{0+2\,k\,\pi\, i}=1$, you could have $\ln(1)=2\,k\,\pi\,i\,$ for any $\,k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Chosing the principal branch (choice $\,k=0\,$ for the picture at the right) gives $\;\ln(1)=0$.

Answer (score 6):

One can define $\ln(x)$ as the unique number $y$ satisfying that
$$
e^y = x.
$$

So, $\ln(1) = 0$ because $e^0 = 1$.

---

You can generalize this to a logarithm with base $b>0$. So $\log_b(x) = y$ means that $b^y = x$.

---

Another definition of the natural logarithm is that
$$
\ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\; dt.
$$
And again,
$$
\ln(1) = \int_1^1 \frac{1}{t}\; dt = 0.
$$

(These definitions are of course equivalent.)

Comment: Thanks, and I get your argument but my question still remains unanswered; Why in the first place is $$e^0 = 1$$ (Why is it that any number raised to $0$ is 1)?

Comment: @KaRJXEN: No, your question was, why is $\ln(1) = 0$? They are technically two different questions. Now the answer to the question why $e^0 = 1$ is that this is a definition. You define $a^n$ ($a>0$) as the product of $n$ with itself $n$ times when $n$ is a natural number. Then you *define* $a^0 = 1$. One reason for this definition is that then the rule $a^na^m = a^{n+m}$ always holds.

Comment: Thanks and I appreciate. But I thought asking $\ln 1 = 0$ would be equivalent to asking $e^0 = 1$. Is there anywhere I could get a proof or an insight on why anything raised to a zero is 1?

Comment: @KaRJXEN: Sure, just search the site. Then you will find, for example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238300/how-to-understand-why-x0-1-where-x-is-any-real-number

Comment: @KaRJXEN: Also, feel free to upvote answers that you appreciate :) Also, you can accept an answer if it answers your question. Both of these things give reputation to the people that took the time to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

In any base,
$$\log(1)=\log(1\cdot1)=\log(1)+\log(1).$$

---

Alternatively,$$\text{antilog}(0)=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$ e^0=1$$
Since the $ \ln$ function is defined as the inverse of the exponential function, i.e., when we write $\ln{x}$ we ask to what power must $e$ be raised to produce $x$. So: $$\ln{1}=0$$

Comment: Thanks, and I get your argument but my question still remains unanswered; Why in the first place is $$e^0 = 1$$ (Why is it that any number raised to $0$ is 1)?

Answer (score 2):

$\ln(x)$ is defined as the value $y$ such that $x=e^y$.

In this case, $\ln(1) = y$ such that $1=e^y$.

Can you see why $y=0$ is the solution now?

Answer (score 1):

$\ln(1+x)=x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dots+(-1)^{k-1}\dfrac{x^k}{k}+\dots$ for $|x|\lt1$.

So if $x=0$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Let's cover how $\ln$ can be defined.

1. $e^{\ln(1)}=1=e^0$, since $e^x$ is an increasing function, it follows that $\ln(1)=0$.
2. $\ln(a)=\ln(1\times a)=\ln(1)+\ln(a)\Rightarrow\ln(1)=0$
3. $\ln(x)=\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt\Rightarrow\ln(1)=\int_1^1\frac{1}{t}dt=0$, without integrating as the lower and upper limits of the integral are the same.
4. $\ln(x^r)=r\ln(x)$, in particular, $\ln(1)=\ln(1^2)=2\ln(1)$, hence $\ln(1)=0$.
5. $\log_a(b)=\frac{1}{\log_b(a)}$, since $\log_1(x)$ cannot be defined, it makes sense for it to be impossible to divide by $\log_x(1)$. Since it is impossible to divide by $0$, it makes sense to let $\log_x(1)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln{1}=0$$
$$\log_e{1}=0$$
$$e^0=1.$$

**Lesson here:** anything to the $0$th-power is $1$.

*Q.E.D.*