# Maximal and prime ideal in an artinian ring

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals, artinian

Could anyone give me a reference for the proof of “ In a commutative artinian ring, every maximal ideal is a minimal prime ideal and every minimal prime ideal is a maximal ideal” ?

Comment: Atiyah's introduction to commutative algebra:commutative ring is Artinian ring iff it is Noetherian ring and the Krull dimension is zero.

Comment: How this is relevant ?

Comment: you can find the definition of Krull dimension in Wikipedia.

Comment: What is your definition of Artinian ring?

Comment: What is your work on the subject ? Is the second part more difficult ?

Comment: @lhf The ring which satisfies d.c.c

Comment: @jean Marie I want to prove the both part, and I don’t know how to use krull dimension for this

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27145/why-are-artinian-rings-of-krull-dimension-0