# If $R$ is a reduced Noetherian ring, then every prime ideal in the total quotient ring $K(R)$ is maximal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

I know that in $K(R)$, the set of maximal ideals is the set of associated primes of $K(R)$ and that an ideal is maximal if and only if it is the localization of a maximal associated prime of $R$.

So, we know there are only finitely many maximal ideals in $K(R)$.

I'm not sure if that is helpful, but, **We want to show that if $R$ is a reduced Noetherian ring, then every prime ideal in $K(R)$ is in fact maximal.**

I'm not sure how to use assumption that $R$ is reduced. All I know is that this means that there are no nilpotent elements in $R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that $Q(R)$ is Noetherian and reduced since $R$ is, and second, every element of $Q(R)$ is either a unit or a zero divisor. Once this is established, we can effectively forget about $R$. With that in mind, all ideals introduced are ideals of $Q(R)$.

Let $\mathfrak{p}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{p}_k$ be the minimal prime ideals of $Q(R)$ (there are finitely many since $Q(R)$ is Noetherian). Recall that the nilradical (the set of nilpotent elements, or equivalently, the radical of the zero ideal) of $Q(R)$ is equal to the intersection of all primes ideals of $Q(R)$. Since $Q(R)$ is reduced, this means that the intersection of the prime ideals is the zero ideal. Furthermore, because every prime ideal contains a minimal prime ideal, the intersection of all prime ideals equals $\cap_{i=1}^k\mathfrak{p}_i$ and therefore $\cap_{i=1}^k\mathfrak{p}_i=(0)$.

We now show that $\mathfrak{p}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{p}_k$ are all maximal ideals. Let $j_1\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and let $I$ be an ideal such that $\mathfrak{p}_{j_1}\subseteq I\subsetneq Q(R)$. Let $x\in I$. Then $x$ is not a unit since $I\neq Q(R)$ which implies $x$ is a zero divisor. So, there exists nonzero $y\in Q(R)$ such that $xy=0$. Since the $y$ is nonzero and $\cap_{i=1}^k\mathfrak{p}_i=(0)$, we see $y\notin\cap_{i=1}^k\mathfrak{p}_i$ and therefore there exists $j_2\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ such that $y\notin \mathfrak{p}_{j_2}$. However, $xy=0\in\mathfrak{p}_{j_2}$, so $x\in\mathfrak{p}_{j_2}\subseteq\cup_{i=1}^k\mathfrak{p}_i$. Thus, we conclude $I\subseteq\cup_{i=1}^k\mathfrak{p}_i$.

Next, by prime avoidance, we deduce that $I\subseteq \mathfrak{p}_{j_3}$ for some $j_3\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and hence $\mathfrak{p}_{j_1}\subseteq\mathfrak{p}_{j_3}$. Because $\mathfrak{p}_{j_3}$ is a minimal prime ideal, this implies $\mathfrak{p}_{j_1}=\mathfrak{p}_{j_3}$ and therefore $I=\mathfrak{p}_{j_1}$. Thus, we conclude $\mathfrak{p}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{p}_k$ are maximal ideals. Finally, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is any prime ideal, then it contains a minimal prime $\mathfrak{p}_j$ for some $j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and hence $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}_j$ by maximality of $\mathfrak{p}_j$, so every prime ideal is maximal.

I have edited my answer to fill in a lot more details, but let me know if you need further clarification on any points.

Comment: Why can you use prime avoidance on $I$? How is $I$ contained in the union of the minimal primes?

Comment: @AlJebr $I$ is contained in the union because $I$ does not contain any units (since $I$ is a proper ideal) and, as established, every nonunit is contained in the union of the minimal primes. Prime avoidance then tells us that since $I$ is contained in the union of the minimal primes, it must be contained in some individual prime.

Comment: It feels like there is a lot of steps missing here. Are you implying that $Q(R)$ is reduced? How do you know that if $xy = 0$, then there is some minimal prime of $\frak p$ of $Q(R)$ such that $xy \in \frak p$?

Comment: $R$ is reduced, but it seems like you are working with $Q(R)$ as the reduced ring.

Comment: @AlJebr Yes, $Q(R)$ is clearly reduced since $R$ is. I didn't want to fill in all the details for you so you could work out the details yourself, but if the answer is too hard to follow, I can certainly edit it to fill in some more details.

Comment: I don't see how if $R$ is reduced, then $Q(R)$ is reduced. If $R$ is reduced, then intersection of all prime ideals is $(0)$. We want to show that after extending every prime ideal in $R$, the intersection in $Q(R)$ remains $(0)$. Why is this true?

Comment: @AlJebr Let $\frac{x}{y}\in Q(R)$ for $x,y\in R$ and suppose $\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^n=0$ for some $n$. Then $x^n=0\cdot y^n=0$ and hence $x=0$ since $R$ is reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are tasked with proving it from scratch, but I figured I'd give another theoretical answer that's useful.

A reduced Noetherian ring is a (special case of a) Goldie ring. [Goldie's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldie%27s_theorem) says that the classical ring of quotients is an Artinian ring, and you probably already know that [prime ideals in an Artinian ring are maximal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27145/29335)

There's another useful theorem:

> **Johnson's theorem** TFAE:
>
> 1. $R$ is a right nonsingular ring
> 2. $Q^r_{max}(R)$ is von Neumann regular

A reduced ring is nonsingular, and a von Neumann regular ring is $0$ dimensional. The only question is whether or not the classical ring of quotients coincides with the maximal ring of quotients in this case (I don't recall and I can't see that it is the case.) One might expect it to hold especially for a commutative Noetherian ring.