# Prime and maximal ideals of $\mathbb C[\mathbb Z_3]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

I'm trying to find these ideals without success.

I have a hint: $\mathbb C[\mathbb Z_3] \simeq \frac{\mathbb C[X]}{(X^3 - 1)}$, considering $\mathbb C[X]$ is a PID.

Edit: How can I prove that ideals of $\frac{\mathbb C[X]}{(X^3 - 1)}$ are the ideals of $\mathbb C[X]$ containing $(X^3 - 1)$?

Comment: what does $\Bbb C[\Bbb Z_3]$ stand for?

Comment: $\mathbb C[\mathbb Z_3] = \displaystyle \left\{{\sum_{n\in{\mathbb Z_3}}{a\cdot n}: a\in\mathbb C}\right\}$

Comment: Use the correspondence theorem

Comment: Ok. Using this theorem, I obtained that the prime ideals of $\mathbb C[\mathbb Z_3]$ are $J = (1 \cdot \overline{1} - w \cdot \overline{0})$ and $w$ is a cube root of unity. Thanks

Comment: @rschwieb why not? I found the prime ideals of $\mathbb C[X]$ that contains $(x^3 - 1)$ and there's only three: $(x - w)$ with $w$ a cube root of unity. That means I have $I_1, I_2$ and $I_3$, $w_1, w_2$ and $w_3$ different cube roots of unity, then $I_1 = (x - w_1)$, $I_2 = (x - w_2)$ and $I_3 = (x - w_3)$. Then "I took" these ideals in $\frac{\mathbb C[X]}{(X^3 - 1)}$ using the correspondence theorem and described them as ideals of $\mathbb C[\mathbb Z_3]$ because there are isomorphic rings.

Comment: @ChristianCoronel Excuse me: I appear to have completely misread the field in question, possibly because I was jumping around between posts looking for a duplicate.  I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

In your edit you are just quoting the [correspondence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/813978/29335) which is available everywhere.

In a polynomial ring like $\mathbb C[x]$ that amounts to factoring $x^3-1$ over $\mathbb C$.  The maximal ideals will correspond to irreducible factors. You should find exactly three.

Because this ring is Artinian (it's finite dimensional over a field after all) its [prime ideals will be exactly its maximal ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27145/29335).