# The intersection of distinct maximal ideals is not prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $P,Q$ be distinct maximal ideals of a ring $R$. Prove that $P\cap Q$ is not prime.

I am not sure how to prove this.  The only facts that I can think of applying are the definitions, $R/M$ is a field iff $M$ is max, and $R/P$ is an ID iff $P$ is prime.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Good idea with the R/P prime approach. Check the ring $R/P\cap Q$ and see if you have any ideals that multiply to zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas, this is what I have: Since P  and Q  are both maximal, neither is contained in the other. Let $p\in P\backslash Q$  and $q\in Q\backslash P$. Then $pq\in P\cap Q$. But neither $p\in P\cap Q$  nor $q\in P\cap Q$. So $P\cap Q$ cannot be a prime ideal of R.

Answer (score 10):

Let $p\in P\setminus Q$ and $q\in Q\setminus P$. (Why can you find such $p,q$?)

Then what can you say about $pq$?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\rm\: R/(I\cap J)\cong R/I \times R/J\:$ has obvious zero divisors $\rm (\bar i,0)(0,\bar j)=(0,0)\:$ if $\rm\:I\not\subset J, J\not\subset I$

Note that the other proofs reduce to this by [factoring out $\rm\:P\cap Q.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3716/242) This ubiquitous modular reduction technique is better learned sooner than later (hence its emphasis in said link by the master algebraist Irving Kaplansky very early in his textbook).