# How distinct maximal ideals have non-empty intersection?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138882/showing-the-intersection-of-maximal-ideals-is-not-prime) I don't understand how distinct maximal ideals have non-empty intersection? I mean since $P, Q$ are distinct does not imply that $P\cap Q=\varnothing$? Or the intersection has another meaning here?

Answer (score 3):

Consider two arbitrary maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$. What is their intersection?

Comment: for example $\langle 3\rangle\cap\langle 2\rangle=0$

Comment: @Danial: No, in $\mathbb{Z}$ the intersection of these two maximal (prime) ideals is another principal ideal, $\langle 6 \rangle$.

Comment: yes yes.. I understand it now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In this context distinct means just that $P\ne Q$, note that any ideal must always contain 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing "distinct" with "disjoint." $P\cap Q=\emptyset$ is "$P,Q$ disjoint."

Comment: This is true :)