# Prove that every prime ideal is a maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

The commutative ring $R$ is defined where every element $a^n=a$ for some $ n\in Z^{+}$ .

Let $cl(b) \in R/P$. As $b \in R \implies b^{n-1}=1$.

Now $cl(b)=b+P$.

```
$ (cl(b))^n =(b+P)^{n} $

             = $b^{n} +.....+(P)^n$ 

              = $b+P = cl(b)$
```

As $R/P$ is an integral domain there are no divisors of zero . Now $(cl(b))^{n-1}=1$. Hence $(cl(b))^{n-2}$ is the inverse of $cl(b)$.
Is this  attempt correct?

Comment: Related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/210940/29335) but since there are salient problems with the solution offered, it might not be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to write $\bar{b}$ instead of $cl(b)$ to make it easier to look at.

There is also a fatal problem with the original statement that "$a^n=a$ for some $n\in \mathbb Z^+$."  This is trivially true in any ring for $n=1\in\mathbb Z^+$.  What was intended is that the integer $n > 1$.

---

As noted by the other solution, it is unwarranted to say that $b^{n-1}=1$ in $R$. But also, you don't even need that.

The remainder is correct except for a technicality handling the case when $\bar{b}=\bar{0}$.

You noted that $\bar{b}^n=\bar{b}$ in $R/P$, which *does* allow cancellation, since it is a domain.  Therefore you can say that *either $\bar{b}=\bar 0$ or $\bar{b}$ cancels*, and in the latter case $\bar{b}$ is invertible in $R/I$, with inverse $\bar{b}^{n-2}$.   That means every element of $R/P$ is invertible or zero, so $R/P$ is a field, and therefore $P$ is maximal.

---

Actually this holds for a larger class of rings called *von Neumann regular rings*.  (Ones that are commutative, that is.) A ring is called von Neumann regular if for every $a$ there exists an $x$ such that $axa=a$. In our case, here, $x=a^{n-2}$. (This exponent is always available since we have assumed $n > 1$.) there is a famous theorem by Jacobson that also says your ring must be commutative, too.

I would put the proof like this: let $P$ be a prime ideal of a von Neumann regular ring.  Note that $(ax)^2=ax$ so $ax$ is an idempotent. Now, in the domain $R/P$, an idempotent must be $\bar 0$ or $\bar 1$, so $\overline{ax}=\bar 0$ or $\overline{ax}=\bar 1$. In the first case, $\bar a=\overline{axa}=\bar 0$, and in the second case $\bar x=\bar{a}^{-1}$. Thus each element is zero or invertible, $R/P$ is a field, and $P$ is maximal.

Answer (score 0):

NO, you cannot simplify by $b$ in $R$. However, you can do it in $R/P$ since its an integral domain, PROVIDED THAT $cl(b)\neq 0$.

If you want to write things properly, you should say first that you take an element $cl(b)\neq 0$ in the quotient, and show that it is invertible.